# Detect whether charset exists in python

Tags: python, character-encoding

Is it possible to check in Python whether a given charset exists/is installed.
For example:
check('iso-8859-1') -> True
check('bla') -> False

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `lookup()` function in the `codecs` module. It throws an exception if a codec does not exist:

```
import codecs
def exists_encoding(enc):
    try:
        codecs.lookup(enc)
    except LookupError:
        return False
    return True
exists_encoding('latin1')
```