# Get a list of all the encodings Python can encode to

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

I am writing a script that will try encoding bytes into many different encodings in Python 2.6. Is there some way to get a list of available encodings that I can iterate over?

The reason I'm trying to do this is because a user has some text that is not encoded correctly. There are funny characters. I know the unicode character that's messing it up. I want to be able to give them an answer like "Your text editor is interpreting that string as X encoding, not Y encoding". I thought I would try to encode that character using one encoding, then decode it again using another encoding, and see if we get the same character sequence.

i.e. something like this:

```
for encoding1, encoding2 in itertools.permutation(encodinglist(), 2):
  try:
    unicode_string = my_unicode_character.encode(encoding1).decode(encoding2)
  except:
    pass
```

Comment: Perhaps you should start a new question, giving details of what the actual problem is, including how you know what is the Unicode character that's messing it up, and what "messing it up" means, and what the "funny characters" are, etc etc. If the offending data is in a file, show the relevant part of the output of `print repr(open('thefile.txt', 'rb').read())`

Comment: I needed this functionality when cleaning non-UTF filenames from a large file share.   There was no telling what the original encoding for many files was... Some of these embedded "odd" single bytes didn't fit any code points in Windows-1252 or ISO-8859, and a useful way of guessing what set they came from was to get Python to convert the single byte to each encoding it can, and see if the result was reasonable. Then fix the filename.

Comment: For example `b'Bj\x94rk'` didn't fit ISO-8859-1 but after trying them all I see it fit CP850 or CP437.

Comment: I implemented a [script](https://github.com/laerreal/test_encodings) which uses ideas of [Anurag Uniyal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1728418/7623015)
and [u0b34a0f6ae](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1728414/7623015) to get list of available codecs. The script also
tests codecs on all byte values and measures performance.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**Unfortunately `encodings.aliases.aliases.keys()` is NOT an appropriate answer.**

`aliases`(as one would/should expect) contains several cases where different keys are mapped to the same value e.g. `1252` and `windows_1252` are both mapped to `cp1252`. You could save time if instead of `aliases.keys()` you use `set(aliases.values())`.

BUT THERE'S A WORSE PROBLEM: `aliases` doesn't contain codecs that don't have aliases (like cp856, cp874, cp875, cp737, and koi8_u).

```
>>> from encodings.aliases import aliases
>>> def find(q):
...     return [(k,v) for k, v in aliases.items() if q in k or q in v]
...
>>> find('1252') # multiple aliases
[('1252', 'cp1252'), ('windows_1252', 'cp1252')]
>>> find('856') # no codepage 856 in aliases
[]
>>> find('koi8') # no koi8_u in aliases
[('cskoi8r', 'koi8_r')]
>>> 'x'.decode('cp856') # but cp856 is a valid codec
u'x'
>>> 'x'.decode('koi8_u') # but koi8_u is a valid codec
u'x'
>>>
```

It's also worth noting that however you obtain a full list of codecs, it may be a good idea to ignore the codecs that aren't about encoding/decoding character sets, but do some other transformation e.g. `zlib`, `quopri`, and `base64`.

Which brings us to the question of WHY you want to "try encoding bytes into many different encodings". If we know that, we may be able to steer you in the right direction.

For a start, that's ambiguous. One DEcodes bytes into unicode, and one ENcodes unicode into bytes. Which do you want to do?

What are you really trying to achieve: Are you trying to determine which codec to use to decode some incoming bytes, and plan to attempt this with all possible codecs? [note: latin1 will decode anything] Are you trying to determine the language of some unicode text by trying to encode it with all possible codecs? [note: utf8 will encode anything].

Comment: I have a reason why to encode the Unicode string as one encoding and decode as another. Some not-so-well-internationalized legacy software write texts in files in one character encoding where another encoding is expected. One example is MP3 files and ID3 tags. Many badly written Chinese MP3 player still encodes metadata in GB18030 (default in Chinese Windows) while labels the tag as LATIN1 or other wrong encoding. Some Python library, e.g. Mutagen, blindly trusts the metadata, and returns wrong str rather than raw bytes. Sometimes the only way to fix the encoding is to try all combinations.

Comment: What's worse, MP3 files from other places of origin may use other different encodings, such as songs in the Japanese language created by Taiwanese singers. If I only know the song is Japanese, I would never imagine the creator used the "big5" encoding (usually for traditional Chinese). That's why I need to try all possibilities. Quodlibet has a "convert encoding" plugin that [does exactly this](https://github.com/quodlibet/quodlibet/blob/master/quodlibet/quodlibet/ext/editing/iconv.py#L42), except its list of encoding is incomplete and sometimes cannot find the actual encoding.

Answer (score 139):

Other answers here seem to indicate that constructing this list *programmatically* is difficult and fraught with traps. However, doing so is probably unnecessary since the documentation contains a complete list of the standard encodings Python supports, and has done since Python 2.3.

You can find these lists (for each stable version of the language so far released) at:

- https://docs.python.org/2.3/lib/node130.html
- https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html
- https://docs.python.org/2.5/lib/standard-encodings.html
- https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings
- https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings
- https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings
- https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings
- https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings
- https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings
- https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings
- https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings
- https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings
- https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings
- https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings
- https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings
- https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings
- https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

Below are the lists for each documented version of Python. Note that if you want backwards-compatibility rather than just supporting a particular version of Python, you can just copy the list from the *latest* Python version and [check whether each encoding exists in the Python running your program](https://stackoverflow.com/a/630974/1709587) before trying to use it.

### Python 2.3 (59 encodings)

```py
['ascii',
 'cp037',
 'cp424',
 'cp437',
 'cp500',
 'cp737',
 'cp775',
 'cp850',
 'cp852',
 'cp855',
 'cp856',
 'cp857',
 'cp860',
 'cp861',
 'cp862',
 'cp863',
 'cp864',
 'cp865',
 'cp869',
 'cp874',
 'cp875',
 'cp1006',
 'cp1026',
 'cp1140',
 'cp1250',
 'cp1251',
 'cp1252',
 'cp1253',
 'cp1254',
 'cp1255',
 'cp1256',
 'cp1257',
 'cp1258',
 'latin_1',
 'iso8859_2',
 'iso8859_3',
 'iso8859_4',
 'iso8859_5',
 'iso8859_6',
 'iso8859_7',
 'iso8859_8',
 'iso8859_9',
 'iso8859_10',
 'iso8859_13',
 'iso8859_14',
 'iso8859_15',
 'koi8_r',
 'koi8_u',
 'mac_cyrillic',
 'mac_greek',
 'mac_iceland',
 'mac_latin2',
 'mac_roman',
 'mac_turkish',
 'utf_16',
 'utf_16_be',
 'utf_16_le',
 'utf_7',
 'utf_8']
```

### Python 2.4 (85 encodings)

```py
['ascii',
 'big5',
 'big5hkscs',
 'cp037',
 'cp424',
 'cp437',
 'cp500',
 'cp737',
 'cp775',
 'cp850',
 'cp852',
 'cp855',
 'cp856',
 'cp857',
 'cp860',
 'cp861',
 'cp862',
 'cp863',
 'cp864',
 'cp865',
 'cp866',
 'cp869',
 'cp874',
 'cp875',
 'cp932',
 'cp949',
 'cp950',
 'cp1006',
 'cp1026',
 'cp1140',
 'cp1250',
 'cp1251',
 'cp1252',
 'cp1253',
 'cp1254',
 'cp1255',
 'cp1256',
 'cp1257',
 'cp1258',
 'euc_jp',
 'euc_jis_2004',
 'euc_jisx0213',
 'euc_kr',
 'gb2312',
 'gbk',
 'gb18030',
 'hz',
 'iso2022_jp',
 'iso2022_jp_1',
 'iso2022_jp_2',
 'iso2022_jp_2004',
 'iso2022_jp_3',
 'iso2022_jp_ext',
 'iso2022_kr',
 'latin_1',
 'iso8859_2',
 'iso8859_3',
 'iso8859_4',
 'iso8859_5',
 'iso8859_6',
 'iso8859_7',
 'iso8859_8',
 'iso8859_9',
 'iso8859_10',
 'iso8859_13',
 'iso8859_14',
 'iso8859_15',
 'johab',
 'koi8_r',
 'koi8_u',
 'mac_cyrillic',
 'mac_greek',
 'mac_iceland',
 'mac_latin2',
 'mac_roman',
 'mac_turkish',
 'ptcp154',
 'shift_jis',
 'shift_jis_2004',
 'shift_jisx0213',
 'utf_16',
 'utf_16_be',
 'utf_16_le',
 'utf_7',
 'utf_8']
```

### Python 2.5 (86 encodings)

```py
['ascii',
 'big5',
 'big5hkscs',
 'cp037',
 'cp424',
 'cp437',
 'cp500',
 'cp737',
 'cp775',
 'cp850',
 'cp852',
 'cp855',
 'cp856',
 'cp857',
 'cp860',
 'cp861',
 'cp862',
 'cp863',
 'cp864',
 'cp865',
 'cp866',
 'cp869',
 'cp874',
 'cp875',
 'cp932',
 'cp949',
 'cp950',
 'cp1006',
 'cp1026',
 'cp1140',
 'cp1250',
 'cp1251',
 'cp1252',
 'cp1253',
 'cp1254',
 'cp1255',
 'cp1256',
 'cp1257',
 'cp1258',
 'euc_jp',
 'euc_jis_2004',
 'euc_jisx0213',
 'euc_kr',
 'gb2312',
 'gbk',
 'gb18030',
 'hz',
 'iso2022_jp',
 'iso2022_jp_1',
 'iso2022_jp_2',
 'iso2022_jp_2004',
 'iso2022_jp_3',
 'iso2022_jp_ext',
 'iso2022_kr',
 'latin_1',
 'iso8859_2',
 'iso8859_3',
 'iso8859_4',
 'iso8859_5',
 'iso8859_6',
 'iso8859_7',
 'iso8859_8',
 'iso8859_9',
 'iso8859_10',
 'iso8859_13',
 'iso8859_14',
 'iso8859_15',
 'johab',
 'koi8_r',
 'koi8_u',
 'mac_cyrillic',
 'mac_greek',
 'mac_iceland',
 'mac_latin2',
 'mac_roman',
 'mac_turkish',
 'ptcp154',
 'shift_jis',
 'shift_jis_2004',
 'shift_jisx0213',
 'utf_16',
 'utf_16_be',
 'utf_16_le',
 'utf_7',
 'utf_8',
 'utf_8_sig']
```

### Python 2.6 (90 encodings)

```py
['ascii',
 'big5',
 'big5hkscs',
 'cp037',
 'cp424',
 'cp437',
 'cp500',
 'cp737',
 'cp775',
 'cp850',
 'cp852',
 'cp855',
 'cp856',
 'cp857',
 'cp860',
 'cp861',
 'cp862',
 'cp863',
 'cp864',
 'cp865',
 'cp866',
 'cp869',
 'cp874',
 'cp875',
 'cp932',
 'cp949',
 'cp950',
 'cp1006',
 'cp1026',
 'cp1140',
 'cp1250',
 'cp1251',
 'cp1252',
 'cp1253',
 'cp1254',
 'cp1255',
 'cp1256',
 'cp1257',
 'cp1258',
 'euc_jp',
 'euc_jis_2004',
 'euc_jisx0213',
 'euc_kr',
 'gb2312',
 'gbk',
 'gb18030',
 'hz',
 'iso2022_jp',
 'iso2022_jp_1',
 'iso2022_jp_2',
 'iso2022_jp_2004',
 'iso2022_jp_3',
 'iso2022_jp_ext',
 'iso2022_kr',
 'latin_1',
 'iso8859_2',
 'iso8859_3',
 'iso8859_4',
 'iso8859_5',
 'iso8859_6',
 'iso8859_7',
 'iso8859_8',
 'iso8859_9',
 'iso8859_10',
 'iso8859_13',
 'iso8859_14',
 'iso8859_15',
 'iso8859_16',
 'johab',
 'koi8_r',
 'koi8_u',
 'mac_cyrillic',
 'mac_greek',
 'mac_iceland',
 'mac_latin2',
 'mac_roman',
 'mac_turkish',
 'ptcp154',
 'shift_jis',
 'shift_jis_2004',
 'shift_jisx0213',
 'utf_32',
 'utf_32_be',
 'utf_32_le',
 'utf_16',
 'utf_16_be',
 'utf_16_le',
 'utf_7',
 'utf_8',
 'utf_8_sig']
```

### Python 2.7 (93 encodings)

```py
['ascii',
 'big5',
 'big5hkscs',
 'cp037',
 'cp424',
 'cp437',
 'cp500',
 'cp720',
 'cp737',
 'cp775',
 'cp850',
 'cp852',
 'cp855',
 'cp856',
 'cp857',
 'cp858',
 'cp860',
 'cp861',
 'cp862',
 'cp863',
 'cp864',
 'cp865',
 'cp866',
 'cp869',
 'cp874',
 'cp875',
 'cp932',
 'cp949',
 'cp950',
 'cp1006',
 'cp1026',
 'cp1140',
 'cp1250',
 'cp1251',
 'cp1252',
 'cp1253',
 'cp1254',
 'cp1255',
 'cp1256',
 'cp1257',
 'cp1258',
 'euc_jp',
 'euc_jis_2004',
 'euc_jisx0213',
 'euc_kr',
 'gb2312',
 'gbk',
 'gb18030',
 'hz',
 'iso2022_jp',
 'iso2022_jp_1',
 'iso2022_jp_2',
 'iso2022_jp_2004',
 'iso2022_jp_3',
 'iso2022_jp_ext',
 'iso2022_kr',
 'latin_1',
 'iso8859_2',
 'iso8859_3',
 'iso8859_4',
 'iso8859_5',
 'iso8859_6',
 'iso8859_7',
 'iso8859_8',
 'iso8859_9',
 'iso8859_10',
 'iso8859_11',
 'iso8859_13',
 'iso8859_14',
 'iso8859_15',
 'iso8859_16',
 'johab',
 'koi8_r',
 'koi8_u',
 'mac_cyrillic',
 'mac_greek',
 'mac_iceland',
 'mac_latin2',
 'mac_roman',
 'mac_turkish',
 'ptcp154',
 'shift_jis',
 'shift_jis_2004',
 'shift_jisx0213',
 'utf_32',
 'utf_32_be',
 'utf_32_le',
 'utf_16',
 'utf_16_be',
 'utf_16_le',
 'utf_7',
 'utf_8',
 'utf_8_sig']
```

### Python 3.0 (89 encodings)

```py
['ascii',
 'big5',
 'big5hkscs',
 'cp037',
 'cp424',
 'cp437',
 'cp500',
 'cp737',
 'cp775',
 'cp850',
 'cp852',
 'cp855',
 'cp856',
 'cp857',
 'cp860',
 'cp861',
 'cp862',
 'cp863',
 'cp864',
 'cp865',
 'cp866',
 'cp869',
 'cp874',
 'cp875',
 'cp932',
 'cp949',
 'cp950',
 'cp1006',
 'cp1026',
 'cp1140',
 'cp1250',
 'cp1251',
 'cp1252',
 'cp1253',
 'cp1254',
 'cp1255',
 'cp1256',
 'cp1257',
 'cp1258',
 'euc_jp',
 'euc_jis_2004',
 'euc_jisx0213',
 'euc_kr',
 'gb2312',
 'gbk',
 'gb18030',
 'hz',
 'iso2022_jp',
 'iso2022_jp_1',
 'iso2022_jp_2',
 'iso2022_jp_2004',
 'iso2022_jp_3',
 'iso2022_jp_ext',
 'iso2022_kr',
 'latin_1',
 'iso8859_2',
 'iso8859_3',
 'iso8859_4',
 'iso8859_5',
 'iso8859_6',
 'iso8859_7',
 'iso8859_8',
 'iso8859_9',
 'iso8859_10',
 'iso8859_13',
 'iso8859_14',
 'iso8859_15',
 'johab',
 'koi8_r',
 'koi8_u',
 'mac_cyrillic',
 'mac_greek',
 'mac_iceland',
 'mac_latin2',
 'mac_roman',
 'mac_turkish',
 'ptcp154',
 'shift_jis',
 'shift_jis_2004',
 'shift_jisx0213',
 'utf_32',
 'utf_32_be',
 'utf_32_le',
 'utf_16',
 'utf_16_be',
 'utf_16_le',
 'utf_7',
 'utf_8',
 'utf_8_sig']
```

### Python 3.1 (90 encodings)

```py
['ascii',
 'big5',
 'big5hkscs',
 'cp037',
 'cp424',
 'cp437',
 'cp500',
 'cp737',
 'cp775',
 'cp850',
 'cp852',
 'cp855',
 'cp856',
 'cp857',
 'cp860',
 'cp861',
 'cp862',
 'cp863',
 'cp864',
 'cp865',
 'cp866',
 'cp869',
 'cp874',
 'cp875',
 'cp932',
 'cp949',
 'cp950',
 'cp1006',
 'cp1026',
 'cp1140',
 'cp1250',
 'cp1251',
 'cp1252',
 'cp1253',
 'cp1254',
 'cp1255',
 'cp1256',
 'cp1257',
 'cp1258',
 'euc_jp',
 'euc_jis_2004',
 'euc_jisx0213',
 'euc_kr',
 'gb2312',
 'gbk',
 'gb18030',
 'hz',
 'iso2022_jp',
 'iso2022_jp_1',
 'iso2022_jp_2',
 'iso2022_jp_2004',
 'iso2022_jp_3',
 'iso2022_jp_ext',
 'iso2022_kr',
 'latin_1',
 'iso8859_2',
 'iso8859_3',
 'iso8859_4',
 'iso8859_5',
 'iso8859_6',
 'iso8859_7',
 'iso8859_8',
 'iso8859_9',
 'iso8859_10',
 'iso8859_13',
 'iso8859_14',
 'iso8859_15',
 'iso8859_16',
 'johab',
 'koi8_r',
 'koi8_u',
 'mac_cyrillic',
 'mac_greek',
 'mac_iceland',
 'mac_latin2',
 'mac_roman',
 'mac_turkish',
 'ptcp154',
 'shift_jis',
 'shift_jis_2004',
 'shift_jisx0213',
 'utf_32',
 'utf_32_be',
 'utf_32_le',
 'utf_16',
 'utf_16_be',
 'utf_16_le',
 'utf_7',
 'utf_8',
 'utf_8_sig']
```

### Python 3.2 (92 encodings)

```py
['ascii',
 'big5',
 'big5hkscs',
 'cp037',
 'cp424',
 'cp437',
 'cp500',
 'cp720',
 'cp737',
 'cp775',
 'cp850',
 'cp852',
 'cp855',
 'cp856',
 'cp857',
 'cp858',
 'cp860',
 'cp861',
 'cp862',
 'cp863',
 'cp864',
 'cp865',
 'cp866',
 'cp869',
 'cp874',
 'cp875',
 'cp932',
 'cp949',
 'cp950',
 'cp1006',
 'cp1026',
 'cp1140',
 'cp1250',
 'cp1251',
 'cp1252',
 'cp1253',
 'cp1254',
 'cp1255',
 'cp1256',
 'cp1257',
 'cp1258',
 'euc_jp',
 'euc_jis_2004',
 'euc_jisx0213',
 'euc_kr',
 'gb2312',
 'gbk',
 'gb18030',
 'hz',
 'iso2022_jp',
 'iso2022_jp_1',
 'iso2022_jp_2',
 'iso2022_jp_2004',
 'iso2022_jp_3',
 'iso2022_jp_ext',
 'iso2022_kr',
 'latin_1',
 'iso8859_2',
 'iso8859_3',
 'iso8859_4',
 'iso8859_5',
 'iso8859_6',
 'iso8859_7',
 'iso8859_8',
 'iso8859_9',
 'iso8859_10',
 'iso8859_13',
 'iso8859_14',
 'iso8859_15',
 'iso8859_16',
 'johab',
 'koi8_r',
 'koi8_u',
 'mac_cyrillic',
 'mac_greek',
 'mac_iceland',
 'mac_latin2',
 'mac_roman',
 'mac_turkish',
 'ptcp154',
 'shift_jis',
 'shift_jis_2004',
 'shift_jisx0213',
 'utf_32',
 'utf_32_be',
 'utf_32_le',
 'utf_16',
 'utf_16_be',
 'utf_16_le',
 'utf_7',
 'utf_8',
 'utf_8_sig']
```

### Python 3.3 (93 encodings)

```py
['ascii',
 'big5',
 'big5hkscs',
 'cp037',
 'cp424',
 'cp437',
 'cp500',
 'cp720',
 'cp737',
 'cp775',
 'cp850',
 'cp852',
 'cp855',
 'cp856',
 'cp857',
 'cp858',
 'cp860',
 'cp861',
 'cp862',
 'cp863',
 'cp864',
 'cp865',
 'cp866',
 'cp869',
 'cp874',
 'cp875',
 'cp932',
 'cp949',
 'cp950',
 'cp1006',
 'cp1026',
 'cp1140',
 'cp1250',
 'cp1251',
 'cp1252',
 'cp1253',
 'cp1254',
 'cp1255',
 'cp1256',
 'cp1257',
 'cp1258',
 'cp65001',
 'euc_jp',
 'euc_jis_2004',
 'euc_jisx0213',
 'euc_kr',
 'gb2312',
 'gbk',
 'gb18030',
 'hz',
 'iso2022_jp',
 'iso2022_jp_1',
 'iso2022_jp_2',
 'iso2022_jp_2004',
 'iso2022_jp_3',
 'iso2022_jp_ext',
 'iso2022_kr',
 'latin_1',
 'iso8859_2',
 'iso8859_3',
 'iso8859_4',
 'iso8859_5',
 'iso8859_6',
 'iso8859_7',
 'iso8859_8',
 'iso8859_9',
 'iso8859_10',
 'iso8859_13',
 'iso8859_14',
 'iso8859_15',
 'iso8859_16',
 'johab',
 'koi8_r',
 'koi8_u',
 'mac_cyrillic',
 'mac_greek',
 'mac_iceland',
 'mac_latin2',
 'mac_roman',
 'mac_turkish',
 'ptcp154',
 'shift_jis',
 'shift_jis_2004',
 'shift_jisx0213',
 'utf_32',
 'utf_32_be',
 'utf_32_le',
 'utf_16',
 'utf_16_be',
 'utf_16_le',
 'utf_7',
 'utf_8',
 'utf_8_sig']
```

### Python 3.4 (96 encodings)

```py
['ascii',
 'big5',
 'big5hkscs',
 'cp037',
 'cp273',
 'cp424',
 'cp437',
 'cp500',
 'cp720',
 'cp737',
 'cp775',
 'cp850',
 'cp852',
 'cp855',
 'cp856',
 'cp857',
 'cp858',
 'cp860',
 'cp861',
 'cp862',
 'cp863',
 'cp864',
 'cp865',
 'cp866',
 'cp869',
 'cp874',
 'cp875',
 'cp932',
 'cp949',
 'cp950',
 'cp1006',
 'cp1026',
 'cp1125',
 'cp1140',
 'cp1250',
 'cp1251',
 'cp1252',
 'cp1253',
 'cp1254',
 'cp1255',
 'cp1256',
 'cp1257',
 'cp1258',
 'cp65001',
 'euc_jp',
 'euc_jis_2004',
 'euc_jisx0213',
 'euc_kr',
 'gb2312',
 'gbk',
 'gb18030',
 'hz',
 'iso2022_jp',
 'iso2022_jp_1',
 'iso2022_jp_2',
 'iso2022_jp_2004',
 'iso2022_jp_3',
 'iso2022_jp_ext',
 'iso2022_kr',
 'latin_1',
 'iso8859_2',
 'iso8859_3',
 'iso8859_4',
 'iso8859_5',
 'iso8859_6',
 'iso8859_7',
 'iso8859_8',
 'iso8859_9',
 'iso8859_10',
 'iso8859_11',
 'iso8859_13',
 'iso8859_14',
 'iso8859_15',
 'iso8859_16',
 'johab',
 'koi8_r',
 'koi8_u',
 'mac_cyrillic',
 'mac_greek',
 'mac_iceland',
 'mac_latin2',
 'mac_roman',
 'mac_turkish',
 'ptcp154',
 'shift_jis',
 'shift_jis_2004',
 'shift_jisx0213',
 'utf_32',
 'utf_32_be',
 'utf_32_le',
 'utf_16',
 'utf_16_be',
 'utf_16_le',
 'utf_7',
 'utf_8',
 'utf_8_sig']
```

### Python 3.5 (98 encodings)

```py
['ascii',
 'big5',
 'big5hkscs',
 'cp037',
 'cp273',
 'cp424',
 'cp437',
 'cp500',
 'cp720',
 'cp737',
 'cp775',
 'cp850',
 'cp852',
 'cp855',
 'cp856',
 'cp857',
 'cp858',
 'cp860',
 'cp861',
 'cp862',
 'cp863',
 'cp864',
 'cp865',
 'cp866',
 'cp869',
 'cp874',
 'cp875',
 'cp932',
 'cp949',
 'cp950',
 'cp1006',
 'cp1026',
 'cp1125',
 'cp1140',
 'cp1250',
 'cp1251',
 'cp1252',
 'cp1253',
 'cp1254',
 'cp1255',
 'cp1256',
 'cp1257',
 'cp1258',
 'cp65001',
 'euc_jp',
 'euc_jis_2004',
 'euc_jisx0213',
 'euc_kr',
 'gb2312',
 'gbk',
 'gb18030',
 'hz',
 'iso2022_jp',
 'iso2022_jp_1',
 'iso2022_jp_2',
 'iso2022_jp_2004',
 'iso2022_jp_3',
 'iso2022_jp_ext',
 'iso2022_kr',
 'latin_1',
 'iso8859_2',
 'iso8859_3',
 'iso8859_4',
 'iso8859_5',
 'iso8859_6',
 'iso8859_7',
 'iso8859_8',
 'iso8859_9',
 'iso8859_10',
 'iso8859_11',
 'iso8859_13',
 'iso8859_14',
 'iso8859_15',
 'iso8859_16',
 'johab',
 'koi8_r',
 'koi8_t',
 'koi8_u',
 'kz1048',
 'mac_cyrillic',
 'mac_greek',
 'mac_iceland',
 'mac_latin2',
 'mac_roman',
 'mac_turkish',
 'ptcp154',
 'shift_jis',
 'shift_jis_2004',
 'shift_jisx0213',
 'utf_32',
 'utf_32_be',
 'utf_32_le',
 'utf_16',
 'utf_16_be',
 'utf_16_le',
 'utf_7',
 'utf_8',
 'utf_8_sig']
```

### Python 3.6 (98 encodings)

*Same as previous version.*

### Python 3.7 (98 encodings)

*Same as previous version.*

### Python 3.8 (97 encodings)

```py
['ascii',
 'big5',
 'big5hkscs',
 'cp037',
 'cp273',
 'cp424',
 'cp437',
 'cp500',
 'cp720',
 'cp737',
 'cp775',
 'cp850',
 'cp852',
 'cp855',
 'cp856',
 'cp857',
 'cp858',
 'cp860',
 'cp861',
 'cp862',
 'cp863',
 'cp864',
 'cp865',
 'cp866',
 'cp869',
 'cp874',
 'cp875',
 'cp932',
 'cp949',
 'cp950',
 'cp1006',
 'cp1026',
 'cp1125',
 'cp1140',
 'cp1250',
 'cp1251',
 'cp1252',
 'cp1253',
 'cp1254',
 'cp1255',
 'cp1256',
 'cp1257',
 'cp1258',
 'euc_jp',
 'euc_jis_2004',
 'euc_jisx0213',
 'euc_kr',
 'gb2312',
 'gbk',
 'gb18030',
 'hz',
 'iso2022_jp',
 'iso2022_jp_1',
 'iso2022_jp_2',
 'iso2022_jp_2004',
 'iso2022_jp_3',
 'iso2022_jp_ext',
 'iso2022_kr',
 'latin_1',
 'iso8859_2',
 'iso8859_3',
 'iso8859_4',
 'iso8859_5',
 'iso8859_6',
 'iso8859_7',
 'iso8859_8',
 'iso8859_9',
 'iso8859_10',
 'iso8859_11',
 'iso8859_13',
 'iso8859_14',
 'iso8859_15',
 'iso8859_16',
 'johab',
 'koi8_r',
 'koi8_t',
 'koi8_u',
 'kz1048',
 'mac_cyrillic',
 'mac_greek',
 'mac_iceland',
 'mac_latin2',
 'mac_roman',
 'mac_turkish',
 'ptcp154',
 'shift_jis',
 'shift_jis_2004',
 'shift_jisx0213',
 'utf_32',
 'utf_32_be',
 'utf_32_le',
 'utf_16',
 'utf_16_be',
 'utf_16_le',
 'utf_7',
 'utf_8',
 'utf_8_sig']
```

### Python 3.9 (97 encodings)

*Same as previous version.*

### Python 3.10 (97 encodings)

*Same as previous version.*

### Python 3.11 (97 encodings)

*Same as previous version.*

---

In case they're relevant to anyone's use case, note that the docs also list some [Python-specific encodings](https://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings), many of which seem to be primarily for use by Python's internals or are otherwise weird in some way, like the `'undefined'` encoding which always throws an exception if you try to use it. You probably want to ignore these completely if, like the question-asker here, you're trying to figure out what encoding was used for some text you've come across in the real world. As of Python 3.7, the list is as follows:

```
["idna",
 "mbcs",
 "oem",
 "palmos",
 "punycode",
 "raw_unicode_escape",
 "rot_13",
 "undefined",
 "unicode_escape",
 "unicode_internal",
 "base64_codec",
 "bz2_codec",
 "hex_codec",
 "quopri_codec",
 "uu_codec",
 "zlib_codec"]
```

Some older Python versions had a `string_escape` special encoding that I've not included in the above list because it's been removed from the language.

Finally, in case you'd like to update my tables above for a newer version of Python, here's the (crude, not very robust) script I used to generate them:

````py
import re
import requests
import lxml.html
import pprint

previous = None
for version, url in [
    ('2.3', 'https://docs.python.org/2.3/lib/node130.html'),
    ('2.4', 'https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html'),
    ('2.5', 'https://docs.python.org/2.5/lib/standard-encodings.html'),
    ('2.6', 'https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings'),
    ('2.7', 'https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings'),
    ('3.0', 'https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings'),
    ('3.1', 'https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings'),
    ('3.2', 'https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings'),
    ('3.3', 'https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings'),
    ('3.4', 'https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings'),
    ('3.5', 'https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings'),
    ('3.6', 'https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings'),
    ('3.7', 'https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings'),
    ('3.8', 'https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings'),
    ('3.9', 'https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings'),
    ('3.10', 'https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings'),
    ('3.11', 'https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings'),
]:
    html = requests.get(url).text
    # Work-around for weird HTML markup in recent versions of Python documentation:
    html = re.sub('<[/]?p>', '', html)
    doc = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
    standard_encodings_table = doc.xpath(
        '//table[preceding::h2[.//text()[contains(., "Standard Encodings")]]][//th/text()="Codec"]'
    )[0]
    codecs = standard_encodings_table.xpath('.//td[1]/text()')
    print("## Python %s (%i encodings)\n" % (version, len(codecs)))
    if codecs == previous:
        print('_Same as previous version._\n')
    else:
        print('```python\n' + pprint.pformat(codecs) + '\n```\n')
    previous = codecs
````

Answer (score 31):

Maybe you should try using the [Universal Encoding Detector](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) (chardet) library instead of implementing it yourself.

```
>>> import chardet
>>> s = '\xe2\x98\x83' # ☃
>>> chardet.detect(s)
{'confidence': 0.505, 'encoding': 'utf-8'}
```

Comment: This was incredibly slow on an 11MB file.

Comment: chardet has an option to read until it reaches some confidence interval.

Comment: I upvoted this a few months ago and would upvote again now if I could

Answer (score 23):

You could [use a technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707709/is-there-a-straightforward-way-to-find-all-the-modules-that-are-part-of-a-python/1707786#1707786) to list all modules in the `encodings` package.

```
import pkgutil
import encodings

false_positives = set(["aliases"])

found = set(name for imp, name, ispkg in pkgutil.iter_modules(encodings.__path__) if not ispkg)
found.difference_update(false_positives)
print found
```

Comment: Seems to work, but note that as well as the standard encodings Python supports this also includes silly encodings like `undefined` (always throws an exception if you try to use it) and `rot_13`. I suggest just using the list of standard encodings from the docs instead.

Comment: I wish this answer was upvoted more. This seems to be the easiest automated way within Python to get a list of codecs usable from within the language. This code allowed me to find out that `latin_1` is a one-for-one translation between ordinals and characters.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower that's one of the best kept and useful secrets in Python.  If you understand the history of Unicode it makes sense though - the first 256 code points in Unicode were defined as the [ISO/IEC-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) character set, known by its alternate name Latin-1.

Comment: For what it's worth, I created a script to generate a list of all 8-bit character codes based on this; it is published at https://tripleee.github.io/8bit/

Answer (score 5):

I doubt there is such method/functionality in codecs module, but if you see `encoding/__init__.py`, search function searches thru encodings modules folder, so you may do the same e.g.

```
>>> os.listdir(os.path.dirname(encodings.__file__))
['cp500.pyc', 'utf_16_le.py', 'gb18030.py', 'mbcs.pyc', 'undefined.pyc', 'idna.pyc', 'punycode.pyc', 'cp850.py', 'big5hkscs.pyc', 'mac_arabic.py', '__init__.pyc', 'string_escape.py', 'hz.py', 'cp037.py', 'cp737.py', 'iso8859_5.pyc', 'iso8859_13.pyc', 'cp861.pyc', 'cp862.py', 'iso8859_9.pyc', 'cp949.py', 'base64_codec.pyc', 'koi8_r.py', 'iso8859_2.py', 'ptcp154.pyc', 'uu_codec.pyc', 'mac_croatian.pyc', 'charmap.pyc', 'iso8859_15.pyc', 'euc_jp.py', 'cp1250.py', 'iso8859_10.pyc', 'koi8_r.pyc', 'unicode_escape.pyc', 'cp863.pyc', 'iso8859_4.pyc', 'cp852.py', 'unicode_internal.py', 'big5hkscs.py', 'cp1257.pyc', 'cp1254.py', 'shift_jisx0213.py', 'shift_jis.pyc', 'cp869.pyc', 'hp_roman8.py', 'iso8859_4.py', 'cp775.py', 'cp1251.py', 'mac_cyrillic.pyc', 'mac_greek.pyc', 'mac_roman.pyc', 'iso8859_11.pyc', 'iso8859_6.py', 'utf_8_sig.py', 'iso8859_3.py', 'iso2022_jp_1.py', 'ascii.py', 'cp1026.pyc', 'cp1250.pyc', 'cp950.py', 'raw_unicode_escape.py', 'euc_jis_2004.pyc', 'cp775.pyc', 'euc_kr.py', 'mac
_greek.py', 'big5.pyc', 'shift_jis_2004.pyc', 'gbk.pyc', 'cp1254.pyc', 'cp1255.pyc', 'cp855.pyc', 'string_escape.pyc', 'cp949.pyc', 'cp1258.pyc', 'iso8859_3.pyc', 'mac_iceland.pyc', 'cp1251.pyc', 'cp860.py', 'cp856.py', 'cp874.py', 'iso2022_kr.py', 'cp856.pyc', 'rot_13.py', 'palmos.py', 'iso2022_jp_2.pyc', 'mac_farsi.py', 'koi8_u.pyc', 'cp1256.py', 'iso8859_10.py', 'tis_620.py', 'iso8859_14.pyc', 'cp1253.py', 'cp1258.py', 'cp437.py', 'cp862.pyc', 'mac_turkish.py', 'undefined.py', 'euc_kr.pyc', 'gb18030.pyc', 'aliases.pyc', 'iso8859_9.py', 'uu_codec.py', 'gbk.py', 'quopri_codec.pyc', 'iso8859_7.py', 'mac_iceland.py', 'iso8859_2.pyc', 'euc_jis_2004.py', 'iso2022_jp_3.pyc', 'cp874.pyc', '__init__.py', 'mac_roman.py', 'iso8859_16.py', 'cp866.py', 'unicode_internal.pyc', 'mac_turkish.pyc', 'johab.pyc', 'cp037.pyc', 'punycode.py', 'cp1253.pyc', 'euc_jisx0213.pyc', 'iso2022_jp_2004.pyc', 'iso2022_kr.pyc', 'zlib_codec.pyc', 'cp932.py', 'cp1255.py', 'iso2022_jp_1.pyc', 'cp857.pyc', 'cp424.pyc',
 'iso2022_jp_2.py', 'iso2022_jp.pyc', 'mbcs.py', 'utf_8.py', 'palmos.pyc', 'cp1252.pyc', 'aliases.py', 'quopri_codec.py', 'latin_1.pyc', 'iso2022_jp.py', 'zlib_codec.py', 'cp1026.py', 'cp860.pyc', 'cp1252.py', 'hex_codec.pyc', 'iso8859_1.pyc', 'cp850.pyc', 'cp861.py', 'iso8859_15.py', 'cp865.pyc', 'hp_roman8.pyc', 'iso8859_7.pyc', 'mac_latin2.py', 'iso8859_11.py', 'mac_centeuro.pyc', 'iso8859_6.pyc', 'ascii.pyc', 'mac_centeuro.py', 'iso2022_jp_3.py', 'bz2_codec.py', 'mac_arabic.pyc', 'euc_jisx0213.py', 'tis_620.pyc', 'shift_jis_2004.py', 'utf_8.pyc', 'cp855.py', 'mac_romanian.pyc', 'iso8859_8.py', 'cp869.py', 'ptcp154.py', 'utf_16_be.py', 'iso2022_jp_ext.pyc', 'bz2_codec.pyc', 'base64_codec.py', 'latin_1.py', 'charmap.py', 'hz.pyc', 'cp950.pyc', 'cp875.pyc', 'cp1006.pyc', 'utf_16.py', 'shift_jisx0213.pyc', 'cp424.py', 'cp932.pyc', 'iso8859_5.py', 'mac_romanian.py', 'utf_8_sig.pyc', 'iso8859_1.py', 'cp875.py', 'cp437.pyc', 'cp865.py', 'utf_7.py', 'utf_16_be.pyc', 'rot_13.pyc', 'euc_jp.p
yc', 'raw_unicode_escape.pyc', 'iso8859_8.pyc', 'utf_16.pyc', 'iso8859_14.py', 'iso8859_16.pyc', 'cp852.pyc', 'cp737.pyc', 'mac_croatian.py', 'mac_latin2.pyc', 'iso2022_jp_ext.py', 'cp1140.py', 'mac_cyrillic.py', 'cp1257.py', 'cp500.py', 'cp1140.pyc', 'shift_jis.py', 'unicode_escape.py', 'cp864.py', 'cp864.pyc', 'cp857.py', 'hex_codec.py', 'mac_farsi.pyc', 'idna.py', 'johab.py', 'utf_7.pyc', 'cp863.py', 'iso8859_13.py', 'koi8_u.py', 'gb2312.pyc', 'cp1256.pyc', 'cp866.pyc', 'iso2022_jp_2004.py', 'utf_16_le.pyc', 'gb2312.py', 'cp1006.py', 'big5.py']
```

but as anybody can register a codec, so that won't be exhaustive list.

Comment: This is plain wrong. There is "1251" and "windows_1251", but you list "cp1251". Ahem, it does not work.

Comment: @user649198 I have no idea what you're talking about; [`cp1251`](http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP1251.TXT) exists (`windows-1251` is an alias of it) and is supported in Python 2.7 and Python 3.

Answer (score 5):

From [Python 3.7.6 Source](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.6/Python-3.7.6.tgz), under **/Tools/unicode/listcodecs.py**:

```
""" List all available codec modules.

(c) Copyright 2005, Marc-Andre Lemburg (mal@lemburg.com).

    Licensed to PSF under a Contributor Agreement.

"""

import os, codecs, encodings

_debug = 0

def listcodecs(dir):
    names = []
    for filename in os.listdir(dir):
        if filename[-3:] != '.py':
            continue
        name = filename[:-3]
        # Check whether we've found a true codec
        try:
            codecs.lookup(name)
        except LookupError:
            # Codec not found
            continue
        except Exception as reason:
            # Probably an error from importing the codec; still it's
            # a valid code name
            if _debug:
                print('* problem importing codec %r: %s' % \
                      (name, reason))
        names.append(name)
    return names


if __name__ == '__main__':
    names = listcodecs(encodings.__path__[0])
    names.sort()
    print('all_codecs = [')
    for name in names:
        print('    %r,' % name)
    print(']')
```

Then:

```
if str(response.encoding) is "undefined" or \
        str(response.encoding) not in names:
    do_something()  # like set default to utf_8 and execute
    pass
```

Answer (score 4):

The Python source code has a script at `Tools/unicode/listcodecs.py` which lists all codecs.

Among the listed codecs, however, there are some that are not Unicode-to-byte converters, like `base64_codec`, `quopri_codec` and `bz2_codec`, as @John Machin pointed out.

Answer (score 4):

```
import os
def encodinglist():
    r=[]
    for i in os.listdir(os.path.split(__import__("encodings").__file__)[0]):
        name=os.path.splitext(i)[0]
        try:
            "".encode(name)
        except:
            pass
        else:
            r.append(name.replace("_","-"))
    return r
```

Comment: Somewhat similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1728414/241211), but certainly distinct.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a programmatic way to list all the encodings defined in the stdlib encodings package, note that this won't list user defined encodings.  This combines some of the tricks in the other answers but actually produces a working list using the codec's canonical name.

```
import encodings
import pkgutil
import pprint


all_encodings = set()

for _, modname, _ in pkgutil.iter_modules(
        encodings.__path__, encodings.__name__ + '.',
):
    try:
        mod = __import__(modname, fromlist=[str('__trash')])
    except (ImportError, LookupError):
        # A few encodings are platform specific: mcbs, cp65001
        # print('skip {}'.format(modname))
        pass

    try:
        all_encodings.add(mod.getregentry().name)
    except AttributeError as e:
        # the `aliases` module doensn't actually provide a codec
        # print('skip {}'.format(modname))
        if 'regentry' not in str(e):
            raise

pprint.pprint(sorted(all_encodings))
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can do this:

```
from encodings.aliases import aliases
print aliases.keys()
```

Comment: This doesn't produce a full list -- codecs that don't have aliases aren't mentioned in the aliases map.