# How to add a new encoding to python 2.6?

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, python-2.6

Yet another encoding problem, I'm dealing with an IBM mainframe using IBM870 encoding which isn't supported by python or nothing else for that matter.

Luckily a gifted coder whipped up a script that generates appropriate encoding definitions for python using character lists availble at [FileFormat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/index.htm)

The list used is this one: [IBM870 character list](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/IBM870/list.htm)

The generated encoding can be seen here: [cp870.py](http://pastebin.com/TJpngqLb)

The system in question is a RHEL 6.3 running python 2.6:

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Aug 28 2012, 10:55:56) 
[GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)] on linux2
```

The cp870.py is placed in:

```
/usr/lib64/python2.6/encodings/
```

The following entries have been added to:

```
/usr/lib64/python2.6/encodings/aliases.py

# cp870 codec
'870'                : 'cp870',
'csibm870'           : 'cp870',
'ibm870'             : 'cp870',
```

The alias is properly parsed as seen here ([thanks to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1736533/164839)):

```
>>> from encodings.aliases import aliases
>>> def find(q):
...     return [(k,v) for k, v in aliases.items() if q in k or q in v]
... 
>>> find('870')
[('ibm870', 'cp870'), ('870', 'cp870'), ('csibm870', 'cp870')]
>>> find('cp870')
[('ibm870', 'cp870'), ('870', 'cp870'), ('csibm870', 'cp870')]
>>> find('ibm870')
[('ibm870', 'cp870'), ('csibm870', 'cp870')]
```

When I tried to encode() some characters it didn't work as planned:

```
>>> 'c'.encode('cp870')
'\x83'
>>> 'č'.encode('cp870')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/encodings/cp870.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is what '\x83' should be according to cp870.py:

```
u'\x83'     #  0x23 -> NO BREAK HERE (U+0083)
```

As I am a novice to python could someone enlighten me as to what else is needed in order for python to properly load and use this encoding?

Comment: I attempted the above steps for Python 2.7,armscii8 However, it did not recognize the key/value pair added in aliases.py Is there anything else I need to do apart from the above steps?           Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 2.x, unicode strings need to be marked with the prefix **u** or **U**. Strings without prefix are in ASCII (or another 8-bit encoding).

Furthermore, python expects your input to be ASCII-encoded (although another encoding can be configured). So, when you put a non-ASCII character in quotes, the interpreter tries to decode it as ASCII, which causes the error which you see.

Thus you need to specif the **u** prefix, and use an **escape sequence** to specify the character:

```
U'\x83'.encode('cp870')
```

Comment: @f10bit: If you do want to enter readable text the way you show, you can first "decode" it into unicode, from whatever encoding your console understands, then encode it to the cp870 encoding.

Comment: Thank you both for the explanation, that's what I've been missing, turns out everything seems to work:  

    `>>> 'đ'.decode('utf8')`
    `u'\u0111'`  
    `>>> u'\u0111'.encode('cp870')`  
    `'\x8c'`  

Here is the relevant line from cp870.py:  

`u'\u0111'   #  0x8C -> LATIN SMALL LETTER D WITH STROKE (U+0111)`