# How do I know all supported encodings recognized by Python's unicode function

Tags: python, character-encoding, python-unicode

Python has a `unicode` built-in function that converts an byte stream to unicode string.

[image]

I just hope I can query all the available *encoding* on my system. But how to.

The reason for this question is: Some one using MAC OS X sent me an email with content-encoding 'iso-2022-cn', and I find that Python 2.7 on Windows 7 does not recognize that encoding.

```
>>> print unicode(bs2022, 'iso-2022-cn')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#97>", line 1, in <module>
    print unicode(bs2022, 'iso-2022-cn')
LookupError: unknown encoding: iso-2022-cn
```

So I'd like to find out whether Python uses a different name for 'iso-2022-cn' by looking at all *encoding* he can support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is  a [list](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) for python 2.7

also you can do this

```
from encodings.aliases import aliases
>>> def find(q):
        q = encodings.normalize_encoding(q)
...     return [(k,v)for k,v in aliases.iteritems() if q in v or q in k]

>>>> find('100')
[('ksx1001', 'euc_kr'), ('iso_ir_100', 'latin_1'), ('ks_x_1001', 'euc_kr')]
```

Comment: Sad, something like ``iso2022_cn`` is not listed on that page. And,  is there a way to query that list from executing Python code?

Comment: add `q = encodings.normalize_encoding(q)` otherwise you might miss an encoding even if it is in the `aliases` map. Also [`aliases` do not give you the full list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1728376/4279)