# SyntaxError: encoding problem: big5 in python

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.9
#-*- coding: big5 -*-
print("柯南")
```

It gives out an Error: `SyntaxError: encoding problem: big5`.
Why it gives out this Error when I actually has specified the coding?
I know by default python is using UTF-8 and it supports traditional chinese. It will fix it
But I really just want to play around with the syntax `#-*- coding: encoding -*-` and know why I get this error.

Comment: I don't think big5 is a valid encoding

Comment: I read this document page https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#source-code-encoding and it references a list of codecs in  https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#module-codecs. big5 is in the list.

Comment: Is your editor saving the file in that encoding?

Comment: I can reproduce the error by saving the file as UTF-8, like @solarc suggests.

Comment: no I will not get an error if I delete the coding line (using the default encoding scheme: UTF-8) or if I specify the coding scheme to be UTF-8.

Comment: I wonder does the supported language in the os will affect the encoding in python

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182296/how-do-i-know-all-supported-encodings-recognized-by-pythons-unicode-function#17182324) for the list of encodings supported. `big5` seems to show as `big5_tw` or `csbig5` so try those.

Comment: Are you essentially trying to decode a UTF-8-encoded file with BIG5?

Comment: @blhsing sorry what do you mean?

Comment: @solarc big5_tw and csbig5 also does not work

Comment: I mean your Python source code was likely saved with UTF-8 encoding, but with the header specifying an incorrect encoding of BIG5, the file can't be decoded properly as a result.

Comment: @bihsing oh yes I try this `mint@vivobook:~/Documents$ file test.py` It gives me the result: `test.py: Python script, UTF-8 Unicode text executable`. Then how can i change the python script into big5 executable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to convert text files between character sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets)