# UnicodeDecodeError when reading CSV file in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, unicode

I'm running a program which is processing 30,000 similar files. A random number of them are stopping and producing this error...

```
  File "C:\Importer\src\dfman\importer.py", line 26, in import_chr
    data = pd.read_csv(filepath, names=fields)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 400, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 205, in _read
    return parser.read()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 608, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1028, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "parser.pyx", line 706, in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas\parser.c:6745)
  File "parser.pyx", line 728, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas\parser.c:6964)
  File "parser.pyx", line 804, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas\parser.c:7780)
  File "parser.pyx", line 890, in pandas.parser.TextReader._convert_column_data (pandas\parser.c:8793)
  File "parser.pyx", line 950, in pandas.parser.TextReader._convert_tokens (pandas\parser.c:9484)
  File "parser.pyx", line 1026, in pandas.parser.TextReader._convert_with_dtype (pandas\parser.c:10642)
  File "parser.pyx", line 1046, in pandas.parser.TextReader._string_convert (pandas\parser.c:10853)
  File "parser.pyx", line 1278, in pandas.parser._string_box_utf8 (pandas\parser.c:15657)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xda in position 6: invalid    continuation byte
```

The source/creation of these files all come from the same place. What's the best way to correct this to proceed with the import?

Answer (score 1219, accepted):

`read_csv` takes an `encoding` option to deal with files in different formats. I mostly use `read_csv('file', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")`, or alternatively `encoding = "utf-8"` for reading, and generally `utf-8` for `to_csv`.

You can also use one of several `alias` options like `'latin'` or `'cp1252'` (Windows) instead of `'ISO-8859-1'` (see [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings), also for numerous other encodings you may encounter).

See [relevant Pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html),
[python docs examples on csv files](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples), and plenty of related questions here on SO. A good background resource is [What every developer should know about unicode and character sets](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

To detect the encoding (assuming the file contains non-ascii characters), you can use `enca` (see [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/enconv)) or `file -i` (linux) or `file -I` (osx) (see [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file)).

Comment: @Ben Here's a good resource [What every developer should know about unicode and character sets](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: ISO-8859-1 has the unique property among Python encodings that it can read absolutely any binary data without throwing an error. Quite often, beginners will try different encodings without actually looking at their resulting data, then wonder why their results are junk when they picked the wrong one.

Comment: @tripleee there aren't "Python encodings" (unless you count things like implementing ROT-13 as an "encoding" in Python's system); ISO-8859-1 is an internationally recognized standard (hence ISO) implemented countless times in countless environments. Ten out of the sixteen ISO-8859 encodings can handle arbitrary binary, as can several historical DOS code pages, legacy Macintosh text encodings, and a few others. ISO-8859-1 *does* have the (necessarily) unique property that it maps those bytes to the first 256 Unicode code points in order, though.

Comment: Sure, I meant amongst the character encodings that Python supports.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Python's documentation states that 'a number of predefined codecs are specific to Python'; these are titled "Python Specific Encodings" (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings). So I think it's accurate to say that there are such things as 'python encodings.'

Answer (score 207):

**Simplest of all Solutions:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv', engine='python')
```

**Alternate Solution:**

*Sublime Text:*

> - Open the csv file in *Sublime text editor* or *VS Code*.
> - Save the file in utf-8 format.
> - In sublime, Click File -> Save with encoding -> UTF-8

*VS Code:*

> In the bottom bar of VSCode, you'll see the label UTF-8. Click it. A popup opens. Click Save with encoding. You can now pick a new encoding for that file.

Then, you could read your file as usual:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

and the other different encoding types are:

```
encoding = "cp1252"
encoding = "ISO-8859-1"
```

Answer (score 44):

Pandas allows to specify encoding, but does not allow to ignore errors not to automatically replace the offending bytes. So there is no *one size fits all* method but different ways depending on the actual use case.

1. You know the encoding, and there is no encoding error in the file. 
   Great: you have just to specify the encoding:

   ```
   file_encoding = 'cp1252'        # set file_encoding to the file encoding (utf8, latin1, etc.)
   pd.read_csv(input_file_and_path, ..., encoding=file_encoding)
   ```
2. You do not want to be bothered with encoding questions, and only want that damn file to load, no matter if some text fields contain garbage. Ok, you only have to use `Latin1` encoding because it accept any possible byte as input (and convert it to the unicode character of same code):

   ```
   pd.read_csv(input_file_and_path, ..., encoding='latin1')
   ```
3. You know that most of the file is written with a specific encoding, but it also contains encoding errors. A real world example is an UTF8 file that has been edited with a non utf8 editor and which contains some lines with a different encoding. Pandas has no provision for a special error processing, but Python `open` function has (assuming Python3), and `read_csv` accepts a file like object. Typical errors parameter to use here are `'ignore'` which just suppresses the offending bytes or (IMHO better) `'backslashreplace'` which replaces the offending bytes by their Python’s backslashed escape sequence:

   ```
   file_encoding = 'utf8'        # set file_encoding to the file encoding (utf8, latin1, etc.)
   input_fd = open(input_file_and_path, encoding=file_encoding, errors = 'backslashreplace')
   pd.read_csv(input_fd, ...)
   ```

Answer (score 34):

This is a more general script approach for the stated question.

```
import pandas as pd

encoding_list = ['ascii', 'big5', 'big5hkscs', 'cp037', 'cp273', 'cp424', 'cp437', 'cp500', 'cp720', 'cp737'
                 , 'cp775', 'cp850', 'cp852', 'cp855', 'cp856', 'cp857', 'cp858', 'cp860', 'cp861', 'cp862'
                 , 'cp863', 'cp864', 'cp865', 'cp866', 'cp869', 'cp874', 'cp875', 'cp932', 'cp949', 'cp950'
                 , 'cp1006', 'cp1026', 'cp1125', 'cp1140', 'cp1250', 'cp1251', 'cp1252', 'cp1253', 'cp1254'
                 , 'cp1255', 'cp1256', 'cp1257', 'cp1258', 'euc_jp', 'euc_jis_2004', 'euc_jisx0213', 'euc_kr'
                 , 'gb2312', 'gbk', 'gb18030', 'hz', 'iso2022_jp', 'iso2022_jp_1', 'iso2022_jp_2'
                 , 'iso2022_jp_2004', 'iso2022_jp_3', 'iso2022_jp_ext', 'iso2022_kr', 'latin_1', 'iso8859_2'
                 , 'iso8859_3', 'iso8859_4', 'iso8859_5', 'iso8859_6', 'iso8859_7', 'iso8859_8', 'iso8859_9'
                 , 'iso8859_10', 'iso8859_11', 'iso8859_13', 'iso8859_14', 'iso8859_15', 'iso8859_16', 'johab'
                 , 'koi8_r', 'koi8_t', 'koi8_u', 'kz1048', 'mac_cyrillic', 'mac_greek', 'mac_iceland', 'mac_latin2'
                 , 'mac_roman', 'mac_turkish', 'ptcp154', 'shift_jis', 'shift_jis_2004', 'shift_jisx0213', 'utf_32'
                 , 'utf_32_be', 'utf_32_le', 'utf_16', 'utf_16_be', 'utf_16_le', 'utf_7', 'utf_8', 'utf_8_sig']

for encoding in encoding_list:
    worked = True
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(path, encoding=encoding, nrows=5)
    except:
        worked = False
    if worked:
        print(encoding, ':\n', df.head())
```

One starts with all the standard encodings available for the python version (in this case 3.7 [python 3.7 standard encodings](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)).
A usable python list of the standard encodings for the different python version is provided here: [Helpful Stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25584253/8667185)

Trying each encoding on a small chunk of the data;
only printing the working encoding.
The output is directly obvious.
This output also addresses the problem that an encoding like 'latin1' that runs through with ought any error, does not necessarily produce the wanted outcome.

In case of the question, I would try this approach specific for problematic `CSV` file and then maybe try to use the found working encoding for all others.

Comment: haha, good job bro.

Answer (score 28):

Please try to add

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', encoding='unicode_escape')
```

This will help. Worked for me. Also, make sure you're using the correct delimiter and column names.

You can start with loading just 1000 rows to load the file quickly.

Answer (score 24):

```
with open('filename.csv') as f:
   print(f)
```

after executing this code you will find encoding of 'filename.csv' then execute code as following

```
data=pd.read_csv('filename.csv', encoding="encoding as you found earlier"
```

there you go

Answer (score 13):

Try changing the encoding.
In my case, `encoding = "utf-16"` worked.

`df = pd.read_csv("file.csv",encoding='utf-16')`

Answer (score 12):

You can always try to detect the encoding of the file first, with `chardet` or `cchardet` or `charset-normalizer`:

```
from pathlib import Path
import chardet

filename = "file_name.csv"
detected = chardet.detect(Path(filename).read_bytes())
# detected is something like {'encoding': 'utf-8', 'confidence': 0.99, 'language': ''}

encoding = detected.get("encoding")
assert encoding, "Unable to detect encoding, is it a binary file?"

df = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding=encoding)
```

Answer (score 7):

In my case, a file has `USC-2 LE BOM` encoding, according to Notepad++. 
It is `encoding="utf_16_le"` for python.

Hope, it helps to find an answer a bit faster for someone.

Answer (score 6):

Try specifying the engine='python'. 
It worked for me but I'm still trying to figure out why.

```
df = pd.read_csv(input_file_path,...engine='python')
```

Comment: This also worked for me. So did encoding = "ISO-8859-1". It's definitely an encoding issue. If a special character is encoded in ANSI, such as an ellipse character (i.e. "..."), and you try to read it in UTF-8, you may get an error. Bottom line is you must know the encoding the file was created with.

Comment: "Encoded in ANSI" is not well-defined. The ANSI term on Windows is a misnomer, and doesn't name any specific encoding; rather, it selects a encoding defined elsewhere in the system's settings.

Answer (score 6):

In my case this worked for python 2.7:

```
data = read_csv(filename, encoding = "ISO-8859-1", dtype={'name_of_colum': unicode}, low_memory=False)
```

And for python 3, only:

```
data = read_csv(filename, encoding = "ISO-8859-1", low_memory=False)
```

Answer (score 5):

Struggled with this a while and thought I'd post on this question as it's the first search result.  Adding the `encoding="iso-8859-1"` tag to pandas `read_csv` didn't work, nor did any other encoding, kept giving a UnicodeDecodeError.

If you're passing a file handle to `pd.read_csv(),` you need to put the `encoding` attribute on the file open, not in `read_csv`. Obvious in hindsight, but a subtle error to track down.

Answer (score 5):

#### Another important issue that I faced which resulted in the same error was:

```
_values = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\Mujeeb\Desktop\file.xlxs")
```

> ^This line resulted in the same error because I am reading an excel file using `read_csv()` method. Use `read_excel()` for reading .xlxs

Comment: Wow, everyone else is talking about encoding issues. Looks like my issue was peculiar.

Answer (score 4):

I am posting an answer to provide an updated solution and explanation as to why this problem can occur. Say you are getting this data from a database or Excel workbook. If  you have special characters like `La Cañada Flintridge city`, well unless you are exporting the data using `UTF-8` encoding, you're going to introduce errors. `La Cañada Flintridge city` will become `La Ca\xf1ada Flintridge city`. If you are using `pandas.read_csv` without any adjustments to the default parameters, you'll hit the following error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 5: invalid continuation byte
```

Fortunately, there are a few solutions.

**Option 1**, fix the exporting. Be sure to use `UTF-8` encoding.

**Option 2**, if fixing the exporting problem is not available to you, and you need to use `pandas.read_csv`, be sure to include the following paramters, `engine='python'`. By default, pandas uses `engine='C'` which is great for reading large clean files, but will crash if anything unexpected comes up. In my experience, setting `encoding='utf-8'` has never fixed this `UnicodeDecodeError`. Also, you do not need to use `errors_bad_lines`, however, that is still an option if you *REALLY* need it.

```
pd.read_csv(<your file>, engine='python')
```

**Option 3:** solution is my preferred solution personally. Read the file using vanilla Python.

```
import pandas as pd

data = []

with open(<your file>, "rb") as myfile:
    # read the header seperately
    # decode it as 'utf-8', remove any special characters, and split it on the comma (or deliminator)
    header = myfile.readline().decode('utf-8').replace('\r\n', '').split(',')
    # read the rest of the data
    for line in myfile:
        row = line.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore').replace('\r\n', '').split(',')
        data.append(row)

# save the data as a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns = header)
```

Hope this helps people encountering this issue for the first time.

Comment: The correct solution in this case would be to establish the correct encoding. Based on a single character, it's hard to say authoritatively, but 0xF1 corresponds to **ñ** in e.g. Latin-1. https://tripleee.github.io/8bit/#f1 has a listing of which character this byte represents in all 8-bit encodings supported by Python. `errors="ignore"` is a supremely bad idea if you care about the integrity of your data.

Comment: @tripleee good point, but that is a solution that is not always available. Sometimes you are given a data set with much say as to how it’s exported

Comment: I don't see how your comment is relevant. If you can export the file in a known encoding yourself, then of course you don't need to figure out the encoding. If you are given a file with an unknown encoding, figuring out which encoding it's in is vastly preferable over blindly guessing, or brutally removing any data which isn't UTF-8. This still assumes that the file is not corrupted or something,, in which case you would need to find and fix the corruption manually _in addition to_ figuring out the correct encoding.

Answer (score 4):

Simply add encoding to your method as below:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sales_data_sample.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")

print(df)
```

Comment: Hi Khalid, this is just a reduced (and less informative) version of the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18172249/18470692). Unless you have anything substantial to add to that solution that makes the answer stand out, please consider removing this answer, and not cluttering the post unnecessarily. Also, for future reference: please add explanatory notes to your answers. That is to say: explain *why* a suggested method solves a problem, so that SO users can learn from it.

Answer (score 3):

I have trouble opening a CSV file in simplified Chinese downloaded from an online bank, 
I have tried `latin1`, I have tried `iso-8859-1`, I have tried `cp1252`, all to no avail.

But **`pd.read_csv("",encoding ='gbk')`** simply does the work.

Comment: None of the encodings you tried have any support for representing Chinese text. GBK is still moderately popular in China, where it is a national standard, but not used much anywhere else. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GBK_(character_encoding)

Answer (score 3):

You can try this.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filepath,encoding='unicode_escape')
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer seems to be the catch-all for CSV encoding issues. If you are getting a strange encoding problem with your header like this:

```
>>> f = open(filename,"r")
>>> reader = DictReader(f)
>>> next(reader)
OrderedDict([('\ufeffid', '1'), ... ])
```

Then you have a byte order mark (BOM) character at the beginning of your CSV file. This answer addresses the issue:

[Python read csv - BOM embedded into the first key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40310042/python-read-csv-bom-embedded-into-the-first-key)

The solution is to load the CSV with `encoding="utf-8-sig"`:

```
>>> f = open(filename,"r", encoding="utf-8-sig")
>>> reader = DictReader(f)
>>> next(reader)
OrderedDict([('id', '1'), ... ])
```

Hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

I am posting an update to this old thread. I found one solution that worked, but requires opening each file. I opened my csv file in LibreOffice, chose Save As > edit filter settings. In the drop-down menu I chose UTF8 encoding. Then I added `encoding="utf-8-sig"` to the `data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\fullpathtofile\filename.csv', sep = ',', encoding="utf-8-sig")`.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Nisse, thanks for the edit. Can you please explain what you changed? I don't see a difference.

Comment: I'm not Nisse, but he added a full stop and a newline before the "Hope this helps" ending.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Jupyter-notebook. And in my case, it was showing the file in the wrong format. The 'encoding' option was not working.
So I save the csv in utf-8 format, and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
with open('filename.csv') as f:
    data = pd.read_csv(f)
```

Looks like it will take care of the encoding without explicitly expressing it through argument

Comment: I'm not sure why this is different than just using `data = pd.read_csv(f)` but it does indeed work.

Answer (score 1):

Check the encoding before you pass to pandas. It will slow you down, but...

```
with open(path, 'r') as f:
    encoding = f.encoding 

df = pd.read_csv(path,sep=sep, encoding=encoding)
```

In python 3.7

Comment: This will just fail earlier if Python is unable to divine the encoding. On modern Python 3 on non-Windows platforms, this will default to UTF-8, and fail if the file is not compatible. On Windows, this will default to whatever the system is configured to default to, so it might work if you are lucky, or produce garbage if you are less lucky.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the problem is with the .csv file only. The file may be corrupted.
When faced with this issue. 'Save As' the file as csv again.

```
0. Open the xls/csv file
1. Go to -> files 
2. Click -> Save As 
3. Write the file name 
4. Choose 'file type' as -> CSV [very important]
5. Click -> Ok
```

Comment: Not sure which program do you use here. Excel?

Comment: open excel file

Comment: This assumes that the CSV was generated from an Excel file, which obviously often isn't the case (and if it is, maybe you should examine your tooling choices critically).

Comment: You are right, but irrespective of the tool used to create the CSV file MS excel has the support to open CSV files, hence you can use it. Also most often CSV files are generated by the excel tool only. If this doesn't work, you can try to use some other source tool.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I could not manage to overcome this issue using any method provided before. Changing the encoder type to `utf-8`, `utf-16`, `iso-8859-1`, or any other type somehow did not work.

But instead of using `pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter=';')`, I used;

> `pd.read_csv(open(filename, 'r'), delimiter=';')`

and things seem working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

One more receipt

```
   import csv
   import chardet
   import pandas

   # io_bytes: BytesIO  <=> input data 

   byte_line: bytes = io_bytes.readline()
   dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(str(byte_line))
   encoding_info = chardet.detect(byte_line)
   io_bytes.seek(0)
   dataframe = pandas.read_csv(
       io_bytes, 
       delimiter=dialect.delimiter, 
       encoding=encoding_info["encoding"],
   )
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try with:

`df = pd.read_csv('./file_name.csv', encoding='gbk')`

Answer (score -1):

Pandas does not automatically replace the offending bytes by changing the encoding style. In my case, changing the encoding parameter from `encoding = "utf-8"` to `encoding = "utf-16"` resolved the issue.