# How to fix open csv error: invalid literal for int() with base

Tags: python-3.x, opencsv

I am trying to read a CSV file but have the error below `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ï»¿893245\n332118\n9334343236\n565480\n78996\n889015\n5056515\n378677914`

```
r = open('my_csv_file.csv')
data = [int(i) for i in r.read().split(',')]
print(data)
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the above code? I am using Windows 10.

After I used `r = open('my_csv_file.csv',,encoding='utf-8-sig')` I still have the `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '893245\n332118\n9334343236\n565480\n78996\n889015\n5056515\n378677914`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python read csv - BOM embedded into the first key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40310042/python-read-csv-bom-embedded-into-the-first-key)

Comment: Nope. i still got ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 893245\n332118\n9334343236\n565480\n78996\n889015\n5056515\n378677914\

Comment: You have to loop over the lines in your CSV before splitting on commas. Any reason you aren't using the `csv` module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r = open('my_csv_file.csv',encoding='utf-8-sig')
[int(i) for i in r.read().split('\n') if len(x)>0]
```

The above code will do the trick.