# Pandas can't read csv file, it replace all to NaN

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I try to read csv file

```
 df = pd.read_csv("raccoons.csv", delimiter=":")
 df.head()
```

and it returns to me

```
 ��c    Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2
 NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN
 NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN
 NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN
 NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN
 NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN
```

inside of file

```
corrds:time:raccoons_bought
55.771393 37.567392:4423O3138:2
55.705458 37.550926:442365718:0
55.83028 37.404815:442244596:0
55.799092 37.452157:442327511:148.00001
55.749785 37.763962:442248573:1
```

Comment: are you sure this is the whole csv? I loaded it up just fine using `StringIO`

Comment: Works fine for me too ( i created a file with the content). Moreover, how do you get four columns of NaN's even though there are just three colons in the csv?

Comment: found string like that 55.64824 37.668399:442O42976:"""5""" and 55.769347 37.567509:442317124:1e-05, i try replace 3 """ to empty '' but it doesn't help

Comment: Marvin idk) it's magic

Answer (score 5):

It probably has to do with the file encoding. You may have to set this when calling read_csv. Check the solutions to find your file encoding provided here: [UnicodeDecodeError when reading CSV file in Pandas with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171739/unicodedecodeerror-when-reading-csv-file-in-pandas-with-python)

I had this same issue and finally solved it using:

```
pd.read_csv(..., encoding = 'utf-16')
```

Comment: That was it on my Mac! Why it is not that well documented?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
path = r"raccoons.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(path, sep=":",dtype=None)
print(df)
```

Answer edited. It worked for me!

Comment: ��c           object
Unnamed: 1    object
Unnamed: 2    object
dtype: object. I try dtype float, object - it doesn't help

Comment: i was try to replace ' ' and ':' to ',' but it still doesn't help.  i was try R notebook, try python3, python2 it all doesn't help me.

Comment: I recreated on ubuntu 17:04 with python 2.7, worked like a charm. My tip would be to check the encoding of your csv file.

looks like that for me
    `$ file -i racoons.csv
    racoons.csv: text/plain; charset=us-ascii`

Comment: seems problem in lines like that  55.64824 37.668399:442O42976:"""5""" and 55.769347 37.567509:442317124:1e-05 or not! I create file with 5 first strings result as always -> NAN(((

Comment: i copied values and pasted in new file it solve my problem, thanks you all for help!