# trying to load a csv into Jupyter Notebooks, getting an error. Not sure how to proceed.

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

Here is the code. Super straightforward.

```
df = pd.read_csv('Superstore-Sales.csv')
df
```

But I am getting the following error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 16: invalid start byte
```

I've never had this error when doing this before.

Any thoughts on a fix? Is there something I'm missing?

I've tried adding unicode= 16 as a perameter. No luck there.

Comment: This is already answered check the link below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171739/unicodedecodeerror-when-reading-csv-file-in-pandas-with-python

Comment: Nice!! That did the trick. I hadn't found that thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

**If the above doesn't work**, then do the following:

- Open the csv file in Sublime text editor.
- Save the file in utf-8 format.
- In Sublime, Click File -> Save with encoding -> UTF-8

Then you can read the file as usual,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```