# Creating dataframe from pandas, unknown error on Pycharm

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that looks like this:[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqLhj.png)

I want to put this data into a dataframe but I get the following errors:

```
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 562, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 790, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Here is my code:

## Import necessary modules

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

# Import data into a dataframe
df = pd.read_csv("ETHData.csv")
df.head()
```

As suggested by some users I changed the `df = pd.read_csv("ETHData.csv",encoding='latin1')` and received this output:

```
0  NaN
1  NaN
2  NaN
3  NaN
4  NaN
```

**Update:**

Simply copying and pasting the data from a .txt format to a .csv format solved the problem. Here is the correct output now:

```
       DateTime  Price [USD]
0  7/30/15 0:00          0.0
1  7/31/15 0:00          0.0
2   8/1/15 0:00          0.0
3   8/2/15 0:00          0.0
4   8/3/15 0:00          0.0
```

Comment: use `pd.read_csv("ETHData.csv",encoding='latin1')`

Comment: Look at this response https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171739/unicodedecodeerror-when-reading-csv-file-in-pandas-with-python?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Could you give us the data in a format we can use to try to replicate your error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be encoding related.  The default for pandas is to decode text in utf-8 format, and your data likely requires english unicode (latin1).  As @pythonic883 says, use:

`pd.read_csv('ETHData.csv', encoding='latin1')`.

Sometimes `iso-8859-1` is required.

`pd.read_csv('ETHData.csv', 'encoding='iso-8859-1')`.

Comment: I made an edit based on what you and others have suggested, I still get an incorrect output