# Can't load csv file through pandas in ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am trying to load a .csv file lying on my desktop using pandas on jupyter notebook and getting the following error:[image]

What's the problem with the code? The same method works on windows. (I'm using ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeDecodeError when reading CSV file in Pandas with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171739/unicodedecodeerror-when-reading-csv-file-in-pandas-with-python)

Comment: question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed)

Comment: Please do not post pictures of error messages and code, post the text directly here on SO.

Comment: @Mr. T  Then in what scenario should the attach picture option be used? I posted picture because it was a too long error.

Comment: Text should be posted as text, so it can be indexed and copied into an IDE or a search engine. Pictures are for graphs etc. Not sure, why you got a too long error - I have definitely seen longer questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try passing `encoding='utf-8'` argument in your `read_csv` function, like this:

```
data = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
filepath = r"/home/aditisp/Documents/Untitled Folder/sonar_data.csv"
##the preceding r denotes a string literal

df = pd.read_csv(filepath)

print(df.head())
```

This worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).