# pandas filter by values in 2 columns, return entire row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I've looked around multiple questions on here and no solution works.
I have a matrix, where I want to filter values in 2 columns and return the *entire row* where this filter applies.

At the moment I have tried:

`mask = (data['sender'] == 'me') & (data['status'] == 'done')
data[mask]`

which makes all values become "NaN".

When I try to apply the mask seperately, I get a DataFrame that contains the correct value in the location, but with all other columns as NaN.

I had also tried a different approach, namely like so:

`data.loc[data['sender' == 'me']` 
which has the same result of turning every value in NaN except for the Row x Column where the value appears..

Comment: I think your solution is correct, only assign output like `df = data[mask]` `print (df)`

Comment: Is possible create some sample data? If not working it seems some data related problem.

Comment: @jezrael it might be a problem with the data.. I can not reproduce it on manually entered values. It happens with values parsed through CSV

Comment: One idea, if create default index values it should help by `data = data.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: Or try `mask = (data['sender'] == 'me').values & (data['status'] == 'done').values`

Comment: @DylanMeeus the problem is in the parsing then.

Comment: So, both those things did not work @jezrael but thank you for the suggestions :)

Maybe important to know that when I just print the data _before_ applying a filter, all the values are present in the right columns. No NaN values :/

Comment: `csv_data = genfromtxt('data.csv', delimiter=';', dtype=None, encoding=None)` is how I get it from a CSV. (genfromtxt being a numpy function)

Comment: Is possible use `data =pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=';')` ?

Comment: I used the numpy one because I could set the encoding to None. with pd I get `UnicodeDecodeError                        `

Comment: Maybe help [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18172249)

Comment: @jezrael Yeah, I've added that :) which generates lookup errors. I will see if I can get the data reading with pandas to work first. Thanks already :)

Comment: Okay so now that I got the CSV loading to work with pandas, it is working as intended. Thanks @jezrael!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
    k=pd.DataFrame()
    k=data[(data['sender'] == 'me') & (data['status'] == 'done')]
    k.head()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, in the end this is the right way to do it, though it was not the issue I had.

I'll just accept this answer as it actually _does_ answer what I should have done. :)