# Importing .csv file in Python 3 from folder

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unicode

There are 2 csv files in same location:
1- candidates.csv
2- Store.csv

When I'm importing candidates.csv filw while using this code, it is getting imported:

```
data=pandas.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Nupur\\Desktop\\Ankit\\candidates.csv")
```

But when I'm using same code for importing Store.csv file, it is giving error:

```
data=pandas.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Nupur\\Desktop\\Ankit\\Store.csv")
```

**Error:**

> UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call
>   last) pandas_libs\parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()
>
> pandas_libs\parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype()
>
> pandas_libs\parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert()
>
> pandas_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8()
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position
>   9: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 data=pandas.read_csv("C:\Users\Nupur\Desktop\Ankit\Store.csv")
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in
>   parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col,
>   usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters,
>   true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows,
>   na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines,
>   parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser,
>   dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal,
>   lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding,
>   dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter,
>   doublequote, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map,
>   float_precision)
>       676                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
>       677 
>   --> 678         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>       679 
>       680     parser_f.**name** = name
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in
>   _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>       444 
>       445     try:
>   --> 446         data = parser.read(nrows)
>       447     finally:
>       448         parser.close()
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in
>   read(self, nrows)    1034                 raise ValueError('skipfooter
>   not supported for iteration')    1035 
>   -> 1036         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)    1037     1038         # May alter columns / col_dict
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in
>   read(self, nrows)    1846     def read(self, nrows=None):    1847
>   try:
>   -> 1848             data = self._reader.read(nrows)    1849         except StopIteration:    1850             if self._first_chunk:
>
> pandas_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()
>
> pandas_libs\parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()
>
> pandas_libs\parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()
>
> pandas_libs\parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data()
>
> pandas_libs\parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()
>
> pandas_libs\parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype()
>
> pandas_libs\parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert()
>
> pandas_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8()
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position
>   9: invalid start byte

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeDecodeError when reading CSV file in Pandas with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171739/unicodedecodeerror-when-reading-csv-file-in-pandas-with-python)

Comment: Ankit, did you tried `encoding='utf-8'` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this,

```
data=pandas.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Nupur\\Desktop\\Ankit\\Store.csv",encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you face an encoding error due to encoding on your file not being the default as mentioned by the `pd.read_csv()` docs , you can find the encoding of the file by first installing [`chardet`](https://pypi.org/project/chardet/) followed by the below code:

```
import chardet    
rawdata = open('D:\\path\\file.csv', 'rb').read()
result = chardet.detect(rawdata)
charenc = result['encoding']
print(charenc)
```

This will give you the encoding of the file.

Once you have the encoding, you can read as :

```
pd.read_csv('D:\\path\\file.csv',encoding = 'encoding you found')
```

or

```
pd.read_csv(r'D:\path\file.csv',encoding = 'encoding you found')
```

You will get the list of all encoding [here](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html)

Hope you find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried:

```
data=pandas.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Nupur\\Desktop\\Ankit\\Store.csv", encoding='utf-8')
```

If above doesn't work then seems you coding format is different, I would suggest to choose few encoding for Windows such as `encoding='iso-8859-1'`, `encoding='cp1252'` or `encoding='latin1'` .

OR try adding `r` in front of the filename, so that it will be considered a "`raw string`" so that backslashes won't be treated specially:

```
data=pandas.read_csv(r"C:\\Users\\Nupur\\Desktop\\Ankit\\Store.csv", encoding='cp1252')
```