# How to fix JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)?

Tags: python, json

I'm translating telugu data to English then writing it into a CSV file. In the process, I've encountered with this error :

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

error at line 
mydata[0][1]=Translator().translate(text=mydata[0[1],dest='en').text

Here's my code :

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import csv
import pandas 
from py_translator import Translator

train = pd.read_csv('ACTSA_telugu_polarity_annotated_UTF.txt')
train.head()
myfile=open('telugudata','w')
with myfile:
    for row in train:
        for dat in train[row]:
            mydata=[]
            mydata.append((dat.split('        ')))
            mydata[0][1]=Translator().translate(text=mydata[0][1],dest='en').text
            writer=csv.writer(myfile)
            writer.writerows(mydata)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573332/jsondecodeerror-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0)

Comment: Can u give us more details about the error? Which line is giving out the error?

Comment: There's no use of JSON anywhere in this script.

Comment: When you do `pd.read_csv()` with pandas, try specifying `encoding = "utf-8"`. [Have a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171739/unicodedecodeerror-when-reading-csv-file-in-pandas-with-python).