# Error in Python Pandas when Reading CSV File

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to read a CSV File, but its throwing an error. I am not able to understand whats the problem with my syntax or do I need to add more attributes to my read_csv.

I tried the solution on

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position
>   21: invalid start byte
>   as well. But its not working

```
import pandas as pd


#Assign file_path variable
file_path = 'rawdump_24th_Sep.csv'

#assign dataframe
df1 = pd.read_csv(file_path,index_col=0)

df.head()
```

**[ERROR]**

> UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call
>   last) pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8()
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position
>   21: invalid start byte
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         6 
>         7 #assign dataframe
>   ----> 8 df1 = pd.read_csv(file_path,index_col=0)
>         9 
>        10 df.head()
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in
>   parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col,
>   usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters,
>   true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter,
>   nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose,
>   skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col,
>   date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands,
>   decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar,
>   comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines,
>   warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map,
>   float_precision)
>       700                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
>       701 
>   --> 702         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>       703 
>       704     parser_f.**name** = name
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in
>   _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>       433 
>       434     try:
>   --> 435         data = parser.read(nrows)
>       436     finally:
>       437         parser.close()
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self,
>   nrows)    1137     def read(self, nrows=None):    1138         nrows =
>   _validate_integer('nrows', nrows)
>   -> 1139         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)    1140     1141         # May alter columns / col_dict
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self,
>   nrows)    1993     def read(self, nrows=None):    1994         try:
>   -> 1995             data = self._reader.read(nrows)    1996         except StopIteration:    1997             if self._first_chunk:
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8()
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position
>   21: invalid start byte`

**UPDATED**

```
import pandas as pd


#Assign file_path variable
file_path = 'rawdump_24th_Sep.csv'

#assign dataframe
df1 = pd.read_csv(file_path,index_col=0)

df1.head()
```

> UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call
>   last) pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8()
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position
>   21: invalid start byte
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         6 
>         7 #assign dataframe
>   ----> 8 df1 = pd.read_csv(file_path,index_col=0)
>         9 
>        10 df1.head()
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in
>   parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col,
>   usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters,
>   true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter,
>   nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose,
>   skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col,
>   date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands,
>   decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar,
>   comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines,
>   warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map,
>   float_precision)
>       700                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
>       701 
>   --> 702         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>       703 
>       704     parser_f.**name** = name
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in
>   _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>       433 
>       434     try:
>   --> 435         data = parser.read(nrows)
>       436     finally:
>       437         parser.close()
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self,
>   nrows)    1137     def read(self, nrows=None):    1138         nrows =
>   _validate_integer('nrows', nrows)
>   -> 1139         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)    1140     1141         # May alter columns / col_dict
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self,
>   nrows)    1993     def read(self, nrows=None):    1994         try:
>   -> 1995             data = self._reader.read(nrows)    1996         except StopIteration:    1997             if self._first_chunk:
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8()
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position
>   21: invalid start byte

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171739/unicodedecodeerror-when-reading-csv-file-in-pandas-with-python

Comment: Thanks Michael It worked. It can now be used by adding encoding = "ISO-8859-1" to the read_csv

Answer (score 0):

**'rawdump_24th_Sep.csv' should be there in the same folder where .py file is saved**

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('rawdump_24th_Sep.csv')
df1
```

Comment: Changed df to df1. The file is in the same folder as the location is mentioned. Updated my question above by changing df to df1

Comment: tried same error 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 21: invalid start byte

Answer (score 0):

if your csv file not suit then you can get this error. You should try another dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Use specific encoding.
pd.read_csv('data.csv', encoding='utf-8')