# Pandas read_csv not working when items missing from last column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I'm having problems reading in the following three seasons of data (all the seasons after these ones load without problem).

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

alphabets = ['a','b', 'c', 'd']
keywords = [''.join(i) for i in itertools.product(alphabets, repeat = 3)]
col_names = keywords[:57]

seasons = [2002, 2003, 2004]

for season in seasons):
    df = pd.read_csv("https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/{}{}/E0.csv".format(str(season)[-2:], str(season+1)[-2:]), names=col_names).dropna(how='all')
```

This gives the following error:

```
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 57 fields in line 337, saw 62
```

I have looked on stack overflow for problems that have a similar error code (see below)but none seem to offer a solution that fits my problem.

[Python Pandas Error tokenizing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039057/python-pandas-error-tokenizing-data)

I'm pretty sure the error is caused when there is missing data in the last column, however I don't know how to fix it, can someone please explain how to do this?

Thanks

Baz

UPDATE:

The amended code now works for seasons 2002 and 2003. However 2004 is now producing a new error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Following the answer below from Serge Ballesta option 2:

[UnicodeDecodeError when reading CSV file in Pandas with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171739/unicodedecodeerror-when-reading-csv-file-in-pandas-with-python)

```
df = pd.read_csv("https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/{}{}/E0.csv".format(str(season)[-2:], str(season+1)[-2:]), names=col_names, encoding = "latin1").dropna(how='all')
```

With the above amendment the code also works for season=2004.

I still have two questions though:

Q1.) How can I find which character/s were causing the problem is season 2004?

Q2.) Is it safe to use the 'latin1' encoding for every season even though there wre originally encoded at 'utf-8>

Comment: this error happens when the first row of the dataset has let's say 5 columns, and then later on a row is found having 7 columns, which confuses python in knowing the actual number of columns. what you could do is to name all the columns first and then import them as a dataframe

Comment: Hi there, please see the amended code and update section of the question above.