# importing a csv file as a pandas dataframe and i encountered a Syntax error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, syntax-error, spyder

i am trying to load a CSV file as a pandas data frame and i keep getting a syntax error. Please find attached my code below

```
import pandas as pd
sose_df = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\hp\Desktop\dataset\top50spotify2019\top50.csv")
print(sose_df.head())
```

Comment: post stack trace and more code.

Comment: use raw string `sose_df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\hp\Desktop\dataset\top50spotify2019\top50.csv")`

Comment: i am getting a UnicodeDecodeError

Comment: what about `pd.read_csv("C:\Users\hp\Desktop\dataset\top50spotify2019\top50.csv", encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeDecodeError when reading CSV file in Pandas with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171739/unicodedecodeerror-when-reading-csv-file-in-pandas-with-python)