# Error while trying to reading csv file to Jupyter

Tags: python, csv, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to read a csv file to my Jupyter notebook using Python 3

```
address = 'C:/Users/X/Y/Z/Data.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(address)
```

This is the message I am getting:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xee in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

Any suggestions? I am having trouble understanding what it wants from me to do with the data in order to load it. 
Thanks a lot !

Comment: You haven't shown anything about how you're trying to read the file. All we can say is that there's an issue with decoding to utf8, but the error already tells you that

Comment: How are you reading CSV?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18171739/12556735 . Similar question