# How do i convert a text file (containing "," as seperator) to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a text file containing the following (around 1 million rows):

**First Line:** 
"column_header", "column_header", "column_header", "column_header"

**Second line onwards:**
"value", "value", "value", "value"

**I  tried the following:**

```
''' try 1 '''
with open(file, 'rt') as f:
    contents = f.readlines()

for i in contents:
    print(i) # ->> seeing the text as ," value ", " value ", "
    x = [_.strip().replace('""', '').split(',') for _ in i]
    print(str(x)) # ->> getting bytez

''' try 2 '''
with open(file, 'rt') as f:
    contents = f.read()

    for i in contents:
        print(str(i)) # ->> text but cannot do anything

''' try 3 '''
frame = pd.read_csv(file, sep=',', doublequote=True, skip_blank_lines=True) # ->> utf parsing error
```

Comment: For try 3 - have you tried passing it an `encoding='...'` where `...` is the encoding of the file?

Comment: An UTF-8 parsing error is more a problem with your text file or your setup (OS, environment, shell) than Pandas. We would need to know your text file (or at least the part that fails), and probably the OS & shell you are using.

Comment: use try 3 with " read_fwf" instead of readcsv

Comment: To be clear, try 3 should work. A UTF error means that there was a problem decoding the text file. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171739/unicodedecodeerror-when-reading-csv-file-in-pandas-with-python

Comment: JonClements: yes, both 'python' as 'c'
00: the above could be taken as example. it errors at index 0, first line i assume
Hari: tried, but cannot convert it to DF rows
wjandrea: see my comment at 00
@AMC: what is the best way to convert a text file (containing values such as shown in my question) to a pd.DataFrame() . For each line  -> row, columns are known

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the text file which I received did not have an encoding utc-8. Therefore, neither of the above worked. My solution: open and save as .txt (utf8 encoding). than use the following python code:

```
file = folder_location + 'report.txt'

''' try 3 '''
frame = pd.read_csv(file, sep=',', doublequote=True, skip_blank_lines=True)
print(frame.head())
```