# pandas: import multiple csv from subfolders if the name contains specific text

Tags: python, pandas, import, python-import

I have a folder located at `C:\Users\Documents\folder` and inside that folder there are 500 randomly named subfolders. Each subfolders has multiple csv files. I want to **import csv files if only their name contain word `client`** from those subfolders and concatenate the imported into one dataframe (lets hope I wont have any RAM issue).

Can someone help? Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do it:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

source_dir = r'C:\Users\Documents\folder'

my_list = []

for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(source_dir):
    for f in filenames:

        if 'client' in f:

            my_list.append(pd.read_csv(os.path.join(root, f)))

concatted_df = pd.concat(my_list)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have tried your code and I got ValueError: No Objects to concatenate....

Comment: probably you need to specify .csv format somewhere(?)

Comment: This solution works if the filenames contain the word client. The .csv extension is deduced from the if 'client' in f line. Do the files contain the word client, or the folders? Are there other .csvs in the folders that should not be included?

Comment: THX. each subfolder contains 3 or 4 csv files. Only 1 or 2 of them contain word 'client'. So some csvs should be excluded.   I run the code again and I have  UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't be decode byte 0xbc in position 2: invalid startbyte.

Comment: THX. I dont know why, but I need to add more specific text to make this code run. The new text need to be like '_client_2020_'.

Comment: You can alter the 'client' text string as needed. As for your encoding error, maybe this will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171739/unicodedecodeerror-when-reading-csv-file-in-pandas-with-python.