# Loading CSV file with binary data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, python-unicode

I am trying to parse a CSV file (from an external data source) where one of the columns uses inconsistent character encodings. Rather than trying to get the data provider to use a consistent encoding, I would like to just read that column as binary data. However, `pandas.read_csv` seems to decode the whole file to a string before parsing, so this is giving me errors (UnicodeDecodeError). Here's a toy example (python 3):

```py
>>> from io import BytesIO
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> csv = b'Encoding,Data\nascii,abc\nwindows-1252,\xae\nutf-8,\xe2\x80\x9c1\xe2\x80\x9d\n'
>>> pd.read_csv(BytesIO(csv))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1130, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1254, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1269, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1459, in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I would like a result equivalent to this:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Encoding': ['ascii','windows-1252','utf-8'],
...                    'Data': [b'abc',b'\xae',b'\xe2\x80\x9c1\xe2\x80\x9d']})
>>> df
       Encoding                          Data
0         ascii                        b'abc'
1  windows-1252                       b'\xae'
2         utf-8  b'\xe2\x80\x9c1\xe2\x80\x9d'
```

Which could (in this toy example) be further processed like this:

```py
>>> df.apply(lambda row: str(row.Data,row.Encoding), axis=1)
0    abc
1      ®
2    “1”
dtype: object
```

I'd prefer solutions using only pandas, but I'm willing to look at other parsing libraries if absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Serge Ballesta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3545273/serge-ballesta) answering [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51763708/12874927)

"Pandas allows to specify encoding, but does not allow to ignore errors not to automatically replace the offending bytes. So there is no *one size fits all* method but different ways depending on the actual use case."

1. So first, try using `Latin1` encoding because it accept any possible byte as input and might be sufficient depending of your use-case (I could run your toy example using this):

   ```
   data_frame = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(csv), encoding="latin1"))
   ```
2. As specified in Serge's answer : "Pandas has no provision for a special error processing, but Python `open` function has (assuming Python3), and `read_csv` accepts a file like object." For your case you might consider using `'backslashreplace'` which replaces the offending bytes by their Python’s backslashed escape sequence:

   ```
   file_encoding = 'utf8'        # set file_encoding to the file encoding (utf8, latin1, etc.)
   with open(path_to_csv, encoding=file_encoding, errors = 'backslashreplace') as my_csv:
     dataframe = pd.read_csv(my_csv)
   ```

Comment: The latin1 solution worked well for me. The original bytes can be easily recovered and the correct encoding applied (`df.apply(lambda row: row.Data.encode('latin1').decode(row.Encoding), axis=1)`. I wasn't able to figure out how to reverse the backslashreplace operation.