# How to resolve UnicodeDecodeError with pd.read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas, import

In the bottom right corner it says utf-8 codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 12: invalid start byte. What does this mean?

[image]

### Traceback

[image]

Comment: Please post the code and not an image of it. Welcome to SO! Please take the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour. SO is not for tutorials. What have you already tried, and what didn't work? Please read How to Ask more generally. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: it means that your data is encoded with a different encoding than `utf-8`. Try to specify another encoding when reading the data in `read_csv`, e.g. `endcoding='latin-1'`

Comment: Please close this duplicate of  [UnicodeDecodeError when reading CSV file in Pandas with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171739/unicodedecodeerror-when-reading-csv-file-in-pandas-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the encoding value of read_csv like so:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("my.csv", encoding="latin-1")
```

The encoding you use should be the same one used by the csv. Here is a list of [Python supported encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).