# UnicodeDecodeError when reading CSV file in Pandas with Python "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte"

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am having having trouble reading a csv file using read_csv in Pandas. Here's the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I have tried a bunch of different encoding types with the file I am dealing with and none seem to work. The file is from Google's Search Ads 360 product, which says the csv should be in the ['UFT-16' format](https://support.google.com/searchads/answer/1184148?hl=en&authuser=0). Strangely, if I open the file in Excel and save it as a utf-8 format, I can use read_csv normally.

I've tried the solutions to a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171739/unicodedecodeerror-when-reading-csv-file-in-pandas-with-python), but they did not work for me. This is the only code I am running:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('path/file.csv')
```

Edit: I read in the file as tab delimited, and that seemed to work. I still don't understand why I got the error I did when I tried to read it in as a normal csv. Any insight into this would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this encoding:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('path/file.csv',encoding='cp1252')
```

Comment: I tried that one already :( 
I should note that when I use that encoding or UTF-16, I don't get the same error. When I use one of these encoding, the csv is not loaded properly. The data is smushed into a few columns.