# I'm having trouble with code on PyCharm. I'm trying to read a csv file but I'm getting a unicode error where it can't read specific bytes in positions

Tags: python, pandas, unicode, pycharm

My code looks like this:
I am using PyCharm as my IDE and the csv file I'm using is from MS Excess. I've encoded the csv as UTF-8. I am trying to read the file using pandas. I want to be able to distinquish between objects and ints when I call df.info() This is also why I didn't change it to 'latin-1' or 'ISO...'

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')  
cols = ['sentiment','id','date','query_string','user','text']  
df = pd.read_csv("trainingandtestdata\\training.1600000.processed.noemoticon.csv", header=None, 
names=cols, encoding='utf-8')#low_memory=False dtype='unicode' encoding='latin1'  
df.head()  
df.info()  
df.sentiment.value_counts()
```

My error looks like this:
How do I fix the can't decode bytes in position xxxx to xxxx?

```
"C:\Users\dashg\PycharmProjects\Twitter Sentiment\venv\Scripts\python.exe" 
"C:/Users/dashg/PycharmProjects/Twitter Sentiment/Reviewer.py"   
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "C:/Users/dashg/PycharmProjects/Twitter Sentiment/Reviewer.py", line 6, in <module>  
    df = pd.read_csv("trainingandtestdata\\training.1600000.processed.noemoticon.csv", header=None,  
names=cols, encoding='utf-8')#low_memory=False dtype='unicode' encoding='latin1'  
  File "C:\Users\dashg\PycharmProjects\Twitter Sentiment\venv\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\io\parsers.py",       line 676, in parser_f      
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)    
  File "C:\Users\dashg\PycharmProjects\Twitter Sentiment\venv\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\io\parsers.py",       line 454, in _read   
    data = parser.read(nrows)   
  File "C:\Users\dashg\PycharmProjects\Twitter Sentiment\venv\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\io\parsers.py",  
line 1133, in read  
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)  
  File "C:\Users\dashg\PycharmProjects\Twitter Sentiment\venv\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\io\parsers.py",   line 2037, in read  
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)  
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 860, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read  
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 875, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory  
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 929, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows  
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 916, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows  
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 2063, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error      
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 51845-51846: invalid continuation 
byte

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

your file doesn't have `utf-8` encoding format while your using `encoding='utf-8'` in `read_csv` method. use other encoding method to help you solve the problem, like `'latin'` or `'ISO-8859-1'`. i refer you to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171739/unicodedecodeerror-when-reading-csv-file-in-pandas-with-python) link for help.

worst case scenario, if none of this works, you can read the file in `'rb'` mode (`open(file, 'rb')`) and parse it yourself by splitting each line of data using csv delimiter!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, but in my case the solution was really easy. My ide is PyCharm 2020.1 and the .csv have the iso-8859-1 encoding, I've tried everything without luck, so I decided to check my ide config. I went to:

1. File
2. Settings
3. Left column: Editor
4. In Editor: File encoding
   Then I add my .csv file with the botton: + which is in the right side, and finally change ide's config. Change it all to iso, because by default was in utf-8 and use the exact character to work with the file, in my case is: ?.
   Hope this work

Answer (score 0):

Its better to save that csv into xlsx and read as

pd.read_excel