# Getting UnicodeDecodeError when I load a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas

When I load and run the code below I get a UnicodeDecodeError. How to resolve this problem?

I have a CSV file in my folder but this type of error is coming and it will not show a list of heads in output. I use Jupyter notebook to run the codes as well as for programming.

```py
import pandas as pd
companies=pd.read_csv('companies.csv')
round2=pd.read_csv('rounds2.csv')
print(round2.head())
```

Comment: Try `pd.read_csv('file_name.csv', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeDecodeError when reading CSV file in Pandas with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171739/unicodedecodeerror-when-reading-csv-file-in-pandas-with-python)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output. What do you understand from that error message? Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 0):

You could try `companies=pd.read_csv('companies.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")` or `companies=pd.read_csv('companies.csv', encoding = "utf-8")`