# How do you access your csv file that u have upload in google colab?

Tags: python, csv, utf-8, decode

I follow this website and until the second last line, it works well.

I encounter a error during

```
sample_df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(uploaded['sa.csv'].decode('utf-8')))
sample_df.head()
```

For `sample_df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(uploaded['sa.csv'].decode('utf-8')))`, it stated this:

```
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-c79110307396> in <module>()
----> 1 sample_df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(uploaded['sa.csv'].decode('utf-8')))

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 2716736: invalid continuation byte
```

For `sample_df.head()`, it stated this:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-c589eab13420> in <module>()
----> 1 sample_df.head()

NameError: name 'sample_df' is not defined
```

Can someone help me pls with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your `sample_df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(uploaded['sa.csv'].decode('utf-8')))` didnot execute it gave encoding error!

So `sample_df` was not created, that is why you got the error `NameError: name 'sample_df' is not defined`

You can try: `pd.read_csv('file', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")`

You can also use one of several `alias` options like `'latin'` instead of `'ISO-8859-1'` (see [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings), also for numerous other encodings you may encounter).

See [relevant Pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), [python docs examples on csv files](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples), and plenty of related questions here on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171739/unicodedecodeerror-when-reading-csv-file-in-pandas-with-python). A good background resource is [What every developer should know about unicode and character sets](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

Comment: Hi. i have tried your suggestion. it gave me this. NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-1eb87d3c4b16> in <module>()
----> 1 read_csv('sentiment', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")

NameError: name 'read_csv' is not defined

Comment: It's `pd.read_csv` because you are using it from pandas

Comment: Will try and let u know soon

Comment: But is this fine to use ISO-8859-1 as my language data is in english?