# Pandas dataframe excel encoding problem, excel ignores encoding?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to encode xlsx file to ISO-8859-1 and it won't do it. Why?
Here is my code:

export_csv = df.to_csv (r'./test.cvs', index = None, sep=";", header=True, encoding="ISO-8859-1")
export_xls = df.to_excel(r'./test.xlsx', index=None, header=True, encoding='ISO-8859-1')

Comment: Have you checked the answer of https://stackoverflow.com/q/18171739/12744275

Comment: Thanks for the information, but this didn't solve the issue. It appears that pandas or excel won't save data with proper encoding.