# Python pandas csv file unicode error and stuffs

Tags: python, pandas, python-unicode

I'm trying to read a csv file on python. The code goes like this -

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Inan")
print(df.head())
```

However it keeps showing the unicode error. Tried putting r,changing the slashes in multiple ways,but it didnt't work,just showed different errors like "file not found". What can I do?

Comment: Please post the full error. Also, did you try the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171739/unicodedecodeerror-when-reading-csv-file-in-pandas-with-python) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this method, It may work

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Inan.csv",  encoding="utf-8")
```

include your file extension also(.csv .xlxs)

Comment: Now it says FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Inan'

Comment: u need to mention Inan.csv  , Include that file extension