# i am trying to use dataset using pandas in ibm cloud error='utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 135-136: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, pandas, cloud

This is the code automatically generated by ibm cloud when i upload my dataset and i tried encoding='latin-1' but still it is giving me error

```
import os, types
import pandas as pd
from botocore.client import Config
import ibm_boto3

def __iter__(self): return 0

if os.environ.get('RUNTIME_ENV_LOCATION_TYPE') == 'external':
    endpoint_3660ea30b8c954806ac4 = 'https://s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud'
else:
    endpoint_3660ea30b8c954806ac4 = 'https://s3.private.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud'

client_3660ea30b8c954806ac4 = ibm_boto3.client(service_name='s3',
    ibm_api_key_id='xjHcqdBlY9iaaD7qu17e6-njKJPFSdGWk4d',
    ibm_auth_endpoint="https://iam.cloud.ibm.com/oidc/token",
    config=Config(signature_version='oauth'),
    endpoint_url=endpoint_3660ea30b8c954806ac4)

body = client_3660ea30b8c954806ac4.get_object(Bucket='spamdetectionmodel-donotdelete-pr-mt98rs41prv05c',Key='spam.csv')['Body']
# add missing __iter__ method, so pandas accepts body as file-like object
if not hasattr(body, "__iter__"): body.__iter__ = types.MethodType( __iter__, body )
df_data_1 = pd.read_csv(body)
df_data_1.head()
```

**Error:**

> 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 135-136: invalid
> continuation byte

Comment: curious why this was tagged "websphere"?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change pandas `encoding` settings, can you try below :

```
df_data_1 = pd.read_csv(body, encoding='utf-8')
```

Or alternatively :

```
df_data_1 = pd.read_csv(body, encoding='ISO-8859-1')
```

Have a read on `encoding` setting, below helped me on resolving such error :

[UnicodeDecodeError when reading CSV file in Pandas with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171739/unicodedecodeerror-when-reading-csv-file-in-pandas-with-python)

Comment: yes i used these too but still giving same error but this is working in my computer but not in ibm cloud

Comment: Not sure about ibm cloud to be honest, try to google it, all the best!