# Jupyter Notebooks: Trouble reading cvs file in Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have trouble reading this csv file downloaded from `kaggle`. I have tried using the utf-8 encoding and it was still not able to read the csv file
[image]

Comment: check this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171739/unicodedecodeerror-when-reading-csv-file-in-pandas-with-python

Comment: Please provide code and error in text form, rather then in image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be some special characters in the file.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"file_path", encoding="latin1")
```

Comment: That worked out perfectly, thank you! How did you know which encoding to use?

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('filename.csv') as file_info:
   print(file_info)
```

The encoding will be at the end.

```
data=pd.read_csv('filename.csv', encoding="encoding from file_info")
```

Works every time.