# How to read a csv file using pands having Japanese characters?

Tags: python, pandas

Do we have any encoding options for Japanese, like we have 'ISO-8859-1' for European characterset:

```
df = pd.read_csv("Raw_data.csv",encoding="ISO-8859-1",dtype='str')
```

If I am using this encoding option for a file with Japanese characters, I am getting output as a string of many question marks.

Comment: Have you tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171739/unicodedecodeerror-when-reading-csv-file-in-pandas-with-python

Comment: Try `encoding='utf-8'`

Answer (score 3):

You can use **cp932** encoding to read the Japanese Text.

`df = pd.read_csv("Raw_data.csv",encoding="cp932")`

Here is the link of [Codec for Japanese](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#:%7E:text=cp932,Japanese).

You can also find codec for other language as well [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)