# unicode decode error while importing Medical Data on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, unicode

I tried importing a medical data and I ran into this unicode error, here is my code:

```
output_path = r"C:/Users/muham/Desktop/AI projects/cancer doc classification"
my_file = glob.glob(os.path.join(output_path, '*.csv'))

for files in my_file:
data = pd.read_csv(files)
   print(data)
```

My error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 3314: invalid start byte
```

Comment: The initial data is not encoded in UTF-8, so you should explicitly add the encoding

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeDecodeError when reading CSV file in Pandas with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171739/unicodedecodeerror-when-reading-csv-file-in-pandas-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

Try other encodings, default one is utf-8

like

```
import pandas

pandas.read_csv(path, encoding="cp1252")
```

or ascii, latin1, etc ...