# I'm trying to load a simple csv archive on my macbook using pandas, but it's returning the biggest error i've ever seen. Yes, i'm using jupyter note

Tags: python, pandas, csv, import, import-csv

I'm using jupyter notebook, and the archive csv is in the same place of the .ipynb archive. This is the error:[image: a simple code, and it's doesn't running]

can someone help me, please? if someone know a course to help me with macos i'll be very grateful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeDecodeError when reading CSV file in Pandas with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171739/unicodedecodeerror-when-reading-csv-file-in-pandas-with-python)

Comment: Don't post code or errors as images.  Images make it harder for us to help.

Comment: Please post error messages as text, not images, as it makes it much easier for us to copy-paste, and helps search engines index pages.

Comment: It would be nice to post result of `head atelie-catalogo-produtos.csv` and `file atelie-catalogo-produtos.csv` to show more information about the input.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
tabela = pd.read_csv("atelie-catalogo-produtos.csv, sep=",")
```

to

```
tabela = pd.read_csv("atelie-catalogo-produtos.csv, sep=",", encoding='utf-8')
```