# UnicodeDecodeError reading a CSV file Traceback (most recent call last)

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

[![

```
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
```

](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxFOF.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxFOF.png)

I used read_csv() function to load in sample2.csv.

I was expecting something like this .....
[image]

For sample1.csv it works fine but for sample2.csv it shows error.

Comment: take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171739/unicodedecodeerror-when-reading-csv-file-in-pandas-with-python)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.