# How to escape the string "\x0a\xfd\x ....." in python?

Tags: python, string, utf-8, byte

I'm a Python3 User. And I'm now face some problem about byte to string control..

First, I'm get data from some server as a byte.

[Byte data] : b'\xaaD\x12\x1c+\x00\x00 \x18\x08\x00\x00\x88\xb4\xa2\x07\xf8\xaf\xb6\x19\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03Q\xfa3/\x00\x00\x00\x1d\x00\x00\x00\x86=\xbd\xc9~\x98uA>\xdf#=\x9a\xd8\xdb\x18\x1c_\x9c\xc1\xe4\xb4\xfc;'

This data isn't escape any string type such as utf-8, unicode-escape ...

Who know the solution how to control these data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@MrE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2494262/mre) says, you need to use the `bytes.decode` method. Or you can provide an encoding to the `str()` initialisation function. You can ignore the errors in the following fashion, but it still produces gibberish:

```
>>> x = b'\xaaD\x12\x1c+\x00\x00 \x18\x08\x00\x00\x88\xb4\xa2\x07\xf8\xaf\xb6\x19\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03Q\xfa3/\x00\x00\x00\x1d\x00\x00\x00\x86=\xbd\xc9~\x98uA>\xdf#=\x9a\xd8\xdb\x18\x1c_\x9c\xc1\xe4\xb4\xfc;'
>>> x.decode("UTF-8", errors="ignore")
'D\x12\x1c+\x00\x00 \x18\x08\x00\x00\x07\x19\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03Q3/\x00\x00\x00\x1d\x00\x00\x00=~uA>#=\x18\x1c_;'
```

But as you said, you don't know the encoding so taking some tips from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728376/get-a-list-of-all-the-encodings-python-can-encode-to), I looped through the available encodings, but didn't see anything intelligible, e.g.

```
>>> for c in codec_list:
...     try:
...         print(str(x, c, errors="ignore"))
...     except:
...         pass
...
D+         Q3/      =~uA>#=_;
枋+     揣灝    Q3/      =褕~uA>#=嵫_鍵渝;
枋+     揣灝    Q3/      =褕~A>#=_銧;
¡à    h©s8®¶    é³      f¨I=qÍ ÿªQû¬æAU©Ü
ד    h©s8®¶    י³      f¨I=qאQ¬AU©
¬D+     ê┤ó°»╢    Q·3/      å=╜╔~ÿuA>▀#=Ü╪█_£┴Σ┤ⁿ;
...
```

Then I had a look at the *Universal Character Encoding Detection* module, [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet), also linked above, but that couldn't find anything:

```
>>> import chardet
>>> chardet.detect(x)
{'encoding': None, 'confidence': 0.0, 'language': None}
```

So perhaps you need to look at how you're obtaining your data, the [chardet documentation has some simple, useful examples](https://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#example-using-the-detect-function).

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode the byte data:

`byte_data.decode("utf-8")`

Comment: however it seems your string has wrong start character so you need to figure what it is encoded in to begin with