# Reading File with Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding

Hello I work with the oreilly book from Allen Downey to learn Python3.x. There is in chapter 9 the example to work with a word-list that is in a file from the Moby Project.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moby_Project

https://web.archive.org/web/20170930060409/http://icon.shef.ac.uk/Moby/

I read the german.txt file with following Python lines.

```py
with open("german.txt") as log:
        for line in log:
                word = line.strip()
                if len(word) > 20:
                        print(word)
```

Some words are read, but there come a break and I get this lines.

```
Amtsueberschreitungen
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "einlesen.py", line 8, in <module>
    for line in log:
  File "/home/alexander/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 394: invalid start byte
```

What symbol is meant? How can I handle this with the python code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing the correct encoding for a file can be tricky.  Let's start by opening the file in binary mode, finding the offending byte, and examining the surrounding characters.

```
>>> with open('german.txt', 'rb') as f:
...     bs = f.read()
... 
>>> bs.find(b'\x82')
24970
>>> bs[24960:24980]
b'nebel\rAndr\x82\rAndy\rAne'
```

So the byte b'\x82' is the final letter in a five-letter word that starts with 'Andr'.

Looking up b'\x82' in [this page](https://tripleee.github.io/8bit/#82) (by Stack Overflow user @tripleee), we can see what characters it might match.  The most likely match, I think, is 'é', giving us the proper name 'André'.  Cross checking against the [list of Python encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings), the most suitable encoding is cp850, a legacy encoding for Western European languages.

This code will read the file without error:

```
>>> with open('german.txt', encoding='cp850') as f:
...     for line in f:
...         # do things with line
```

If you find any "unusual" characters in the data you might need to try alternative encodings.  This is because it's quite possible for 8-bit encodings to decode a byte successfully, but the result is meaningless.  For example, if we decode from cp1252:

```
>>> b'Andr\x82'.decode('cp1252')
'Andr‚'
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation of `open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

> if encoding is not specified the encoding used is platform dependent: locale.getpreferredencoding(False) is called to get the current locale encoding.

So how the file will be read is different for everyone. To guarantee that the file is read correctly *you need to specify the correct encoding*.

According to the [documentation of the Moby Project on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moby_Project), "some non-ASCII accented characters remain, represented using *Mac OS Roman* encoding". In the [documentation of the Python `codecs` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html) you can find the correct name for that codec, which is 'mac_roman'. So, you could use the following code, which does not result in a decoding error:

```py
with open("german.txt", 'rt', encoding='mac_roman') as log:
    for line in log:
        word = line.strip()
        if len(word) > 20:
            print(word)
```

**UPDATE**

Despite the documentation, the file does not seem to be encoded using Mac OS Roman encoding. I decoded the file using [all possible encodings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25584253/10669875) and compared the results. There are only 9 non-ASCII words in the list, and the word "André" seems right, as pointed out in another answer. The following is a list of possible encodings (that did not fail, and included the word "André") and the 9 non-ASCII words decoded according to that encoding:

```
encodings: cp437, cp860, cp861, cp863, cp865
words: André, Attaché, Château, Conférencier, Cézanne, Fabergé, Lévi-Strauss, Rhônetal, p≥ange

encodings: cp720
words: André, Attaché, Château, Conférencier, Cézanne, Fabergé, Lévi-Strauss, Rhônetal, pٌange

encodings: cp775
words: André, Attaché, Chāteau, Conférencier, Cézanne, Fabergé, Lévi-Strauss, Rhōnetal, p“ange

encodings: cp850, cp858
words: André, Attaché, Château, Conférencier, Cézanne, Fabergé, Lévi-Strauss, Rhônetal, p‗ange

encodings: cp852
words: André, Attaché, Château, Conférencier, Cézanne, Fabergé, Lévi-Strauss, Rhônetal, p˛ange
```

For all the above-mentioned encodings, the first 8 words are the same when decoded. Only for the last word there are 9 different results.

Based on this results, I *think* that the **cp720** encoding was used. However, I don't recognize the last word from the list, so I can't tell for sure. It's up to you to decide which decoding is most suitable for you.

Comment: +1 thorough, and demonstrating how difficult it can be to accurately determine _exactly_ which 8-bit encoding has been used.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment above, this looks like an encoding issue which, after testing it, is pretty much the case.

Detecting the encoding by using the [`chardet` module](https://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#example-detecting-encodings-of-multiple-files) gives:

```
{'encoding': 'Windows-1252', 'confidence': 0.73, 'language': ''}
```

Which is not Python's  default `UTF8`-encoding. In order to read files with other encodings, you need to specifiy the desired encoding when reading the file by using the `encoding=` parameter of the `open(filename, mode, encoding, ...)` function.

Since the encoding might not be known in advance, it is quite handy to use [chardet's UniversalDetector](https://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/chardet.html#module-chardet.universaldetector) to determine the file encoding and then pass it to the file reading like this:

```
from chardet.universaldetector import UniversalDetector

detector = UniversalDetector()
detector.reset()
with open('german.txt', 'rb') as file:
    for line in file:
        detector.feed(line)
        if detector.done:
            break
detector.close()
encoding = detector.result
print(encoding)

with open("german.txt", encoding=encoding) as log:
    for line_num, line in enumerate(log):
        word = line.strip()
        if len(word) > 20:
            print(line_num, word)
```

---

*Note: Works fine on my machine with German locales (MacOS 10.10.5 with Python 3.6.2) and got the same error before detecting the encoding as the OP did. My locales are:*

```
LANG="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
```

Comment: +1 for using chardet, although in this  case I think chardet is right not to be 100% confident about its findings.

Comment: It's still guessing. And since only 9 of the 159809 words are non-ASCII words, it might be easy to get a high confidence, even with an incorrect encoding. If you look at the actual file, you'll see that decoding it with Windows-1252 will result in the following 9 non-ASCII words: Andr‚, Attach‚, Chƒteau, Conf‚rencier, C‚zanne, Faberg‚, L‚vi-Strauss, Rh“netal, pòange. This does not seem correct to me!